# About asking questions

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes, etiquette

I signed up to Stack Exchange to get help from this community and asked a question. Nobody answered and it was down-voted 10 times by this community. I was wondering what could have I done wrong? Have people lost values? Nobody seems to provide any suggestions of rights and wrongs to the least of which I would have really appreciated. It is cowardice.

Comment: _"It is cowardice."_ You're sounding so similar. Is that a sock puppet asking? Give some latin to approve please.

Comment: The last question you asked on this site was a programming question. This isn't [so]. Programming questions are off-topic here. You expect us to upvote and answer stuff that is off-topic?

Comment: Thanks Oded...That was helpful. Because i was asked to sign up for Stack Exchange i thought it to be the same.

Comment: Each and every of our sites has a help link at the top - it links to several resources, including the tour which explains the scope of the site.

Comment: Ok I got it. I was curious to know the answer.

Comment: hey πάντα ῥεῖ you know who I am?

Comment: I am pretty sure the sock-puppet comment is because that sentence is usually used by sock-puppets

Comment: @AnthonyPham if you follow the possible duplicate link, you might understand his comment. Also, that's probably the reason why he chose that question as dupe target.

Answer (score 4):

Its worth remembering that the way the stackexchange sites work is *fundamentally different* from how the average forum works, because they're not forums.

They tend to have specific scopes - and the [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)(And *seriously* - spend the 3-5 minutes on this on sites you want to interact on) and [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) pages cover that.

> I was wondering what could have I done wrong?

You asked an off topic question (and the least you could have done is linked the specific question). In the case of this question, I suppose we can consider it "This question does not show any research effort" (You can see tooltips by hovering over the voting buttons).

> Have people lost values?

No, things are working as designed. I wouldn't even blame [Tim Post's keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) for that. People downvoted it for valid reasons.

> Nobody seem to provide any suggestions of rights and wrongs to the least of which I would have really appreciated.

You asked an explicitly off topic question. People do this far too much, often to get around a ban on SO. I suppose patience for this has waned.

> It is cowardice.

There's no obligation to explain a downvote in these parts. There's an implicit obligation to try to get things on the right site.