# Does down-vote get reviewed or can I apply for review if got downvoted

Tags: discussion, review, down-votes

Friend of mine, got upvoted for one of his nice answer and got downvoted for same answer by someone without any reason. Even reason for downvote is also not mentioned in comment.

It is assumed that low quality answer or answer with lots of mistakes can get downvoted without reasons, but this was really good answer.

Is there any way to get this down-vote reviewed by moderator as this is real bad experience to have down vote on good answer without proper/silly reason.

Reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596173/10522579)

**Note:** I think if down-voting is not reviewed because it is personal opinion then it will play big role in case of bounty award question. Please explain.

**Update:**

Another example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54196212/10522579).

*Why downvoting should be reviewed if applied for review?*

Newcomers coming across the community sometimes get offended due to getting down-votes with no explanation or with no valid reason. Community sometimes trust person by their experience of rewards got (reputations & badges) only.

To grow community with active users, it can be possible to provide such a thing under revision of higher privileged users. Also we can define some rules so that we can reduce 'downvote reviews' less in numbers. (e.g. downvote review can be applied once per week if no comments on downvote present). Of course, there is lot of things that can be build on this, like we had designed review audit (one of smart mechanism).

Comment: Have you [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)

Comment: Note that if you hover over the downvote button, you'll see a tooltip, that's the default downvote reason so no comment is necessary.

Comment: @RobertLongson So you mean 'This answer is not useful' is simple reason but in what case? Answer is provided as per question asked and it was well accepted by lots of people. Might be case that he have different issue

Comment: Voting (up or down) requires no justification. Anybody can vote however they want at any time, for any reason—good or bad—or for no reason at all. And it's completely anonymous. That's how the system is designed. There can be no such thing a "review."

Comment: Lots of people vote in elections. Should we investigate all those who don't vote for the winning candidate as they've clearly done it wrong because that candidate provided the best answers to the electorate's questions?

Comment: @RobertLongson You are not getting all cases, I got down-voted for my answer in bounty question by same user who answered for that question. I lost bounty award just because this strategy got played. So I asked about this.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well I suppose you have an answer for my question asked now in earlier comment

Comment: Upvotes are also personal opinions.  And those were given without reason, too.  Should we review those as well?

Comment: @ray: "*I got down-voted for my answer in bounty question by same user who answered for that question.*" How exactly do you know this? Voting is anonymous, so how do you know that the downvoter was the poster of a competing answer?

Comment: @NicolBolas I appreciate your question and up/downvote given. But it was pre-assumption of possible case which cannot be detected, mentioned at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322232/447465

Comment: I am developer so I do not work with morality('do not take downvote personally'), I deal with edge conditions which made me ask this question

Comment: @ray: But you wrote about it like it was something you *knew* happened specifically to you, not a "possible case". Indeed, you specifically said "I lost bounty award just because this strategy got played." So I ask again: do you ***know*** that this happened to you, or are you merely suspecting that it happened?

Comment: @ray: "*I deal with edge conditions which made me ask this question*" A good developer only deals with edge cases only to the extent to which they actually matter.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry for my previous words if I went in wrong direction to explain thing but there is such a case present

Comment: @ray: You still haven't answered my question: how do you ***know*** "there is such a case present"? Not merely that it could happen, but that it ***did happen***.

Comment: @NicolBolas for bounty amount I was going to downvote competing answer to  my answer and gonna win half amount but I did not because my ethics did not allow. So my ethics won but it is not same with everyone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1302/discussion-between-ray-and-nicol-bolas).

Comment: I've offered a possible explanation for that down vote on that latest example you provided.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. There isn't. In theory, a downvote can be reversed after an edit, but there is no mechanism for reviewing a downvote.

That said, the reputation penalty is probably small enough that the upvotes overwhelm the downvotes and it should be fine. It's entirely possible the downvoter just had a bad day or something.

Comment: I think same. Also it can be ignored as cost got paid is 2 reputations and he also paid 1 reputation. But it really make me disturbed thinking about it because even single silly reason also was not provided for it

Comment: @ray - I thought it was your friend who got downvoted?