# Bounty Award Case on Same Score

Tags: discussion, voting, bounties

I have case on Stack Overflow where I answered a question having some bounty award. It isn't accepted yet, but it has a positive score. Apparently, another answer provided by another user has some upvotes as well and we have the same score.

If both answers are not getting accepted, then possible half the bounty award will be provided to the one who get highest positive score or earlier answer if both have the same score. So this can be a case where:

1. I can downvote (by my perspective with a silly/valid reason) his answer and get half the award.
2. Same can be done by him to me and win half the award.

Is there any Stack Overflow policy or mechanism to prevent/inspect such action?

Comment: @MEE I know how it works on same score, I am asking about 2 cases mentioned above. Is there any mechanism to detect?

Comment: Sorry I misread your post. Have deleted my comment and retracted my flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no policy or mechanism to prevent this. Voting is anonymous, and only serial voting is acted upon; this will be just one instance. It's a relatively rare case, though, not enough to warrant the amount of code that needs to be written to prevent this.

Therefore, ([Matthew 7:12](https://biblehub.com/nasb/matthew/7.htm)) applies:

> In everything, therefore, treat people the same way you want them to treat you

Vote on the competing answer according to its content, and expect/hope the other user will do so, too. And don't forget we're only talking about a handful of imaginary Internet points.

Comment: So true as I follow same, Asked on general perspective

Comment: Also it is important to note that reputation equals trust from the community and showing this kind of behavior shows that one is not having the trust and therefore should not have the reputation. If someone should exhibit an suspicious pattern of "rep-farming", the moderators could theoretically ask the developers to look at it and take appropriate actions. Although this is very unlikely because no one sees who voted for a post (as Glorfindel said)