# How to correct a mistakenly posed downvote?

Tags: support, voting

And in principle an upvote too. I am on the mobile app, and sometimes it happened to me that I mistakenly evaluated an answer.

Then I found the answer locked until further editing and I can't correct my vote.

Is there a way to fix this other than inviting the author of the answer to slightly edit their work?

Comment: I should've searched before posting an answer ...

Comment: I should have searched as well. :) @Glorfindel

Answer (score 0):

If you can improve anything in the post (grammar corrections, formatting), you can edit it yourself (or in your case, suggest an edit, since you don't have the necessary 2k reputation). Your solution is fine as well (just be sure to remove the comment afterwards).

Otherwise, don't worry to much about a single vote. They happen accidentally for [all kinds of reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/295232).