# What to do when you put two days of formulating a question and it still gets downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, new-users, post-ban

I have spent hours reading, formulating practice questions, using grammar check, and studying research papers.

I have taken a break from Stack Exchange for probably 4 days, hoping that this will refresh the quality in my questions. But, this strategy has failed.

I'm baffled right now, because I took into consideration of what other users have mentioned.  And, it indeed improved my question quality.

### Question

*What other strategies should be used as this strategy no longer works*?

Comment: I'm being question blocked and questions closed, even after hours of formulating. I must not be a very smart guy.

Comment: The Dunning Kruger effect would mean that the prior statement is true.

Comment: @fbueckert Now, what to do when you are doing your best and it doesn't work?

Comment: If you've spent hours as you said, did you put any of that effort into your question?

Comment: This one yes, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/43817/provide-a-counterexample-that-a-language-is-not-in-np

Comment: @fbueckert I formulate on paper. Then ask

Comment: Well...we have set standards here.  Those *must* be met.  Most people *can* meet them, it just requires more effort.  Whether to put in that effort or not is a personal choice.  Those that choose not to, eventually hit a question ban.  It doesn't happen overnight, either; you have to have a history of low quality contributions to hit it.

Comment: I don't know enough about how cstheory works to say if that's acceptable or not.  A quick read makes it look like it's okay, but you only have one downvote, so...I don't know if this is good or not.  And if you are question banned, guaranteed, you have deleted questions that *weren't* so good.

Comment: The amount of time spent building/curating/working on a question isn't a metric we use to determine whether or not the question is on topic/useful.

Comment: @fbueckert If this much time is spent, then I need to look into what caused the downvote. Maybe, its the assertion of statements?

Comment: It's a single downvote.  Let it go.  The bigger issue is the history of low quality deleted questions you have that put you in the ban in the first place.

Comment: @fbueckert Well, I just undelete the bad questions and reformulate them into good ones. Then share them if I have too.

Comment: Don't edit your questions to turn them into different questions; that generally ends badly, especially if they already have answers.  Old questions are not meant to be used as a workaround for the question ban.  Edit them to make them *better*.  If they're unsalvagable...well, there isn't going to be much you can do but wait six months.

Comment: @fbueckert Six months of reddit questions...

Comment: Well, you had your chance here; it's sort of unreasonable to expect us to allow you to continue asking bad questions forever.

Comment: As this question is about a *single* downvote, I feel this question's answer is relevant: [Should 'drive by' downvoting be more effectively caught?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught)

Comment: Additonally, reading [this answer](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1628) you got would likely help you a lot.

Comment: Another problem is that your question looks just like a homework dump. The title sounds just like an assignment, and the contents of the question (except the bottom) sounds just like you're copying it from the assignment. It indicates to regular users that you're just asking others to do your work for you. A better question would have been titled with your actual problem--*I can't formulate a counterexample that shows shift(L) does not overlap NP and P.*--then continued with a short description of what you are trying, and what you have done, followed then by all the details needed by answerers

Comment: @fbueckert I did take that into consideration, I took a break. I did study more detailed. Its just the prior questions are the problem. Not, the newer ones. They are clearly of more quality.

Comment: You don't *have* any newer questions on CS.SE, so that doesn't seem like it's correct.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm question banned.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm already getting views from social media. It'll help my questions.

Comment: Views help nothing at all. Only upvotes do. Sidenote: upvoting your posts with sockpuppets makes more bad things happen.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm not upvoting them. If others are doing it. Using the internet to improve question quality is not against the rules.

Comment: Asking friends to upvote is very much against the rules, and will result in consequences, either for you, them, or both. We vote on content, not on who posts it.

Comment: @fbueckert That's simple don't ask.

Comment: Well, as long as it's asked on the right site, then sure.  No issues with sharing.  It doesn't automatically mean the question is good, or on-topic, but how you handle that is your choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** start by posting on the right site. Read the tour (/tour) and the help center article "What topics can I ask about here?" (/help/on-topic) before asking a question.

---

You've posted a question about Computer Science on Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange. Sounds good, right? Well, [not exactly](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tour).

> **Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for *professional researchers in theoretical computer science* and related fields.

There's a separate site for 'regular' Computer Science questions: [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com). They do appreciate well-researched questions but they don't need to be research *level*.

The same difference applies to MathOverflow (research level) and Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: When in doubt, read the tour of the site you're posting on. It dispells a lot of confusion like this.

Comment: The user is question banned on CS.SE, so, next site, cstheory.

Comment: @fbueckert - Doesn’t make his CS.SE question within scope at CSTheory.SE, but you know that, so your comment is confusing

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, that wasn't what I meant, but that was my fault; I didn't explain myself at all.  It was more an observation that users have a habit of moving to the next, "best" site to ask a question when prevented from asking on the site they want.  It doesn't excuse it, and it doesn't help them, and it's an indicator that the ban was justified.

Comment: @fbueckert Yep, its a good thing. The content is still there and I'll make sure its isn't permanent. As long as questions are in a formal language and practical, then there will be a reduction in downvotes.

Comment: @TravisWells Just follow the directions in the dupe about question bans, and you'll do fine.  Most of it boils down to showing effort, so do that, and it'll be fine, eventually.  Bans are hard by design to get out of, so you really have to work at it.

Comment: @fbueckert Well, a month of re-editing my questions to make salvage of what can be saved and sharing them on social media is the best that can be done within the rules. Till, then its reddit.