# The voting tooltip for answers should be expanded to match the one on questions

Tags: feature-request, answers, tooltips, wording

When you hover over the question vote arrows, the tool tip that shows gives a short description why someone may vote that way

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear.

> This question does not show research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Answers on the other hand have very short voting tool tips in comparison

> This answer is useful.

> This answer is not useful.

I think for the sake of consistency, the answer tool tips should be updated to match the question ones

> This answer is useful; it is clear and accurate.

> This answer is not useful; it is unclear or inaccurate.

Those are just quick suggestions I came up with but it would make the tool tips much more consistent.

I did find [another request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331052/the-descriptions-on-the-vote-buttons-for-answers-should-be-updated-to-be-as-help) to do this but it focuses more on how the wording of the tip influences the way people vote, where as here, I just think it should look consistent. If that is enough of a difference to warrant a new question, I am not sure but I will post anyway and let you decide. It is a small change for sure but I think the UI being consistent is important.