# Up-vote frequency per capita ordered by country

Tags: discussion, voting, data-explorer, statistics, location

As a social experiment, I'm curious to know if users in certain countries up-vote more than others. Maybe the answers help users in some regions more than others, or maybe users in those regions are quicker to the upvote. Or maybe it's totally random.

I tried to group my upvotes by hour-of-day in SEDE, which might give an indication of trends by continent, but the time in the `Votes.CreationDate` is scrubbed for privacy reasons. So is `Votes.UserId`. Is there any way to figure this out, with or without Data Explorer?

Here's the SEDE [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1508305/my-answer-upvotes-by-hour-of-day) I started working on (and abandoned):

```sql
-- PostTypeId = 1:Questions, 2:Answers
-- VoteTypeId = 2:Upvotes, 3:Downvotes, 5:Bookmarks

declare @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT
  DATEPART(hour, v.CreationDate) vote_hour,
  count(1)
FROM Votes v, Posts p
WHERE v.PostId = p.Id
  AND p.OwnerUserId = @UserId
  AND p.PostTypeId = 2
  AND v.VoteTypeId = 2
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, v.CreationDate)
ORDER BY vote_hour;
```

Comment: You might be better off using the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-reputation-history).

Comment: While there's probably some variation due to different social norms, assuming you control for absolute number of visitors from each region, I'd expect that votes are significantly more concentrated on posts near the time they were posted (and near times that the question is bumped; i.e. edits, new answers). Overall, I'd expect that to be very hard to control for, particularly if only looking at the votes received by a single user.

Comment: A simple opinion, I would be especially careful with this type of suggestion. What initially is an *innocent social experiment* to establish some kind of distinction by country, can lead to the beginning of a somewhat more delicate situation. In fact, the question touches on some elements of a certain sensitivity: - regions that *simply show their gratitude more freely* - .

Comment: @Danielillo Totally agree. Thanks for totally pointing that out. I changed that wording to reflect my neutral intention more accurately. I will keep my research neutral and superficial.

Comment: What you're going to find is that most people don't fill out a region, or their region can't be matched to a single, real location.

Comment: @Laurel for example, I am in the holy earth.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't figure this out. And I imagine that even Stack Exchange would need to do some serious effort in combining multiple data sources to get a rough estimate at best.

First of all: No one is required to provide a country. There is no field "Country" in the user table, there is no field "Country" anywhere on your user profile. The closest field that could be linked to / relate to country is the "Location" field.

Location is not mandatory. Only [25% of Stack Overflow users provided a Location](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1508381)
Location is a free text field. It has [255,862 different values](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1508381).

Let's assume for a moment we're allowed to use the internal SEDE instance which has much more tables and don't have the votes table sanitized. To get the country they might be able link the vote of a user to the IP address belonging to that user. I don't have info on how much of that data is kept. Then use the IP address to do a country lookup. If we forget VPN's for a moment and assume most users are likely to use Stack Overflow from the country that match their nationality this could give you a rough guestimate. Additionally they might use Google Analytics data to enhance their data.

I think it is not possible to get an accurate vote frequency per capita ordered by country. And if we did it is unclear how that specific statistic is going to help improve voting as a mean of content quality rating. I can't deny it sometimes looks like voters didn't make the mental switch when they closed Facebook with its cat pictures and opened a Stack Overflow Regex question and continued "liking" what they see. But that is not a country specific problem that is going to be solved with statistics. That needs better upfront guidance, psychology, social behavior studies and mind reading. And probably more keyrings so you're less likely to [lose your key](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397)