# Communicate with Anonymous Voters

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting, anonymous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Feature request: @Downvoter sends a notification to all downvoters for your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post)

I just got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842711/what-is-the-easiest-and-or-approved-way-to-replace-a-built-in-php-function/5842720#5842720) downvoted.

I couldn't care less about the negative vote, but I would like to learn the reason that led to the vote.

Since votes are supposed to be anonymous there isn't anyway I can communicate with whomever voted me, so I would like to suggest the implementation of following meta @identifiers:

- **@up** - notifies all the users that voted up a specific answer / question
- **@down** - notifies all the users that voted down a specific answer / question
- **@voter** - notifies all the users that voted on a specific answer / question

The voters would then be aware of the comment and could choose to keep the anonymity or not.

Obviously the identifiers don't need to be exactly these. Good idea or...? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If downvoters had cared to make a comment explaining their vote, they would have. No need for more noise. And I struggle hard to see a need for `@up` or `@voter`.

Answer (score 5):

Disagree, I believe there would be a lot of noise comments on [top voters](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all) inboxes

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to wager that you got downvoted by the OP.  All of the other non-accepted answers in that question were also downvoted, around the same time.  In fact, the OP proceeded to go through about ten of my highest voted answers and downvote them as well.  It was *quite* entertaining watching her rep decrease at the same time as mine did.

I expect that this is going to end up getting reversed by the vote fraud script.