# Encourage editing downvoted Questions and Answers

Tags: feature-request, badges, edits, voting, badge-request

The problem is that once you downvote a post, the odds that you constantly check for improvements to reverse the downvote of the post are close to nonexistent.

I think that by implementing the following suggestions will drastically increase the willing to improve the poor posts:

- Add a section with a list of all the downvotes posts that have been edited after you downvoted them
- Consider making minor changes to the vote-locking system to allow more flexibility on downvoted posts (that are edited after your downvote)
- Create a new badge for vote-reviewing X number of posts on your downvote list

**To successfully 'vote-review' a post, you will have to chose between:**

1. Remove the downvote
2. Upvote
3. Leave the downvote

Once you correctly review a post, it will will disappear from your list.

Also, the name for the badge could be something that suggests a second chance was given

Comment: Two counterpoints: Edits bump the post, giving it more eyeballs and (if it has improved) votes to counter the old ones; and there's something to be said for letting someone who posted something not great to take a downvote hit and make sure the lesson sticks.  I'm not saying this is a bad idea, in fact I would personally like to be able to review posts edited after I've downvoted.  I'm just not sure the current way is much of a problem.

Comment: What exactly would be the criteria for this badge? I've only seen a general idea proposed, which is good, but you haven't really mentioned what the badge is for. Just reviewing your posts that you previously downvoted isn't really badge-worthy.

Comment: @animuson well, like all badges, they are just an incentive to make us do things we wouldn't normally do without them. And about the criteria, I will think how to improve it and be more descriptive, for now I will focus on the main idea

Comment: I've often thought that getting a buddy to put a -1 on a question would be a good way to get reputation and answers -- it stands out in the question list, gets people to look at it -- and some might pity vote back to zero once they see it's a reasonable question after all. Just a theory...

Comment: I really like this idea, I think it encourages high quality Q&A. And it discourages drive by down voting.. I also had a thought that @downvoters in the comments could act as a notification to the people who downvoted while maintaining anonymity.. that way you could be asking people to re-review  EDIT : D'oh the suggestion is already out there ;-) : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions that are edited are automatically bumped to the top of the front page.  That's how we give them more exposure.

When I downvote a post, I leave a comment that explains how the post can be improved, and I go do something else.  Later, I review all comments I leave; this takes me back to the post I downvoted.  If the user improves their post, I remove my downvote.

The best solution is to carefully compose a new question completely, before you post it.  Most users who post marginal questions never bother to improve them.

Comment: I never thought of commenting to later go back! This is really a neat trick :). It would take me some time to write something contributive so it isn't spam, but certainly this is much less time compared to search them manually

Comment: This is very nice, but... how many users carefully review all their comments later on?

Comment: @NeilFein: The ones that care enough to do so.  Putting in another system is not going to make them care more.

Comment: Badges as proposed here? No, that's not gonna do much. Most users (I'd venture) barely know badges exist, or really care about them. A notification "[foo] post has been edited" in your SE dropdown menu? That I would support.