# Down vote tracking

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, down-votes, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should you be notified if something you vote on is edited? Why can you change your vote after something's been edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135626/should-you-be-notified-if-something-you-vote-on-is-edited-why-can-you-change-yo)

This maybe implemented already, and I just haven't noticed, so please excuse my ignorance. But is there any system for tracking when changes have been made to posts that you down voted?

If not, it would be really nice to have (I'm thinking of SO here) the site send you a notification when changes have been posted on thinks you down voted (be they questions or answers).

The point of downvotes+commenting is to let posters know of problems, incorrect statements, or general issues they they **could** fix. So it seems only right to let you know when edits have been made on something you downvoted to see if it corrects the issue you've noted.

Comment: Related: [Should you be notified if something you vote on is edited? Why can you change your vote after something's been edited?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135626/should-you-be-notified-if-something-you-vote-on-is-edited-why-can-you-change-yo)

Comment: very similar to my proposal http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124471/encourage-editing-downvoted-questions-and-answers