# Add "psuedo-reply" phrases to the @reply scheme

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, comment-replies

I just had this idea, which would make stuff a bit easier.

It goes like this: add some psuedo-reply phrases, which do not reply to a user, rather they reply to a class of users/an unknown user.

Please take into account other, smaller sites when considering these. On SO, much of this functionality can be achieved via a chat/MSO post, but not on smaller sites.

Examples of psuedoreplies:

- On a question with close votes, someone with 3k rep can see that a question has CVs, but is not able to ask the CVers for justification. Many times, I feel that a post marked as off-topic is on-topic, and want to see if there was some other reason for vote-to-close. After seeing the justification, I may decide to CV myself {*}.  In this case, something like `@closevoters` would be nifty.

That's my main request, the other psuedoreplies are just afterthoughts:

- On chat, if I want to ask a mod something, I have to type the mod usernames and see which one is autosuggested. On Physics.SE, fortunately, I don't really have to do this, but I imagine that an `@mods` psuedo-reply would be useful. Of course, it should only ping site-mods who have been on chat recently--only the mods who you could `@reply` to in the first place. If none are online, it should catch the attention of a site-mod when one logs in.
- I can think of other ones-- `@answerers`, to ping all answerers of a question at once, and `@editors`.

I'm not sure how useful this would be, thus I've also tagged this [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

{*} Here's an example: [Boltzmann Brain Immortality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23013/7433) . Someone marked it as close->off-topic->migrate to meta.P.SE. Except that meta.physics.SE is not for discussing metaphysics. I'd like to get that message to the CVer. I'll post some more examples of questions where a CV-explain is necessary IMO if they come by.

Comment: @downvoters, care to explain? ;) (I actually agree with downvoters that this wouldn't be overly helpful).

Comment: See also: [Feature request: @Downvoter sends a notification to all downvoters for your post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37090)

Comment: @George Personally, I feel `@downvoter would get to I whiny. Actually the only one I think necessary is @closevoters, available to 3k reps. The rest are just supplementary ideas I got while writing this post.

Comment: You can already @ the editor of your question by name so how would @editors be helpful?

Comment: @M.Babcock I know; the other psuedoreplies were afterthoughts.

Comment: +1, but I'm sure this would be horribly abused.  But it would be fun to watch the butthurt flow before it was removed.

Comment: @Won't: That's my concern as well..  But the use of `@closevoters` doesn't seem too prone to abuse if its available to 3k rep only.

Answer (score 1):

While an interesting set of functionality, I think it isn't particularly needed, since MSO fills many of those needs. Particularly for dealing with close/delete-votes and mod interaction, a post on Meta will often generate a large amount of discussion and is likely to work better than simply pinging.

I equate it to putting up a flier in a high-traffic area vs. calling each of the people you *might* be able to get an answer from. More people will see the flier and can write their response, which also lets others who are interested see that response, and those that are not can ignore it with no real trouble.

Comment: Im not just talking about SO--mainly about smaller sites. On SO, if there is enough reason to CV, the question will get closed within minutes. On the other hand, on a site like Physics, you see a lone CV, and wonder why its there. I want to help close questions, but I want to have a good reason as well. Nobody really visits meta.P.SE, so this doesn't apply here.

Comment: Ahh, yes, all of these do make _much_ more sense on smaller sites, but not on SO.

Comment: @Manishearth - Wouldn't chat be a better vehicle for that sort of thing?

Comment: @M.Babcock 1) You don't know who closevoted. 2) Chat and meta on smaller sites like Physics are ghost towns. The person you want to notify has probably not joined the room recently so `@replies don't work.

Comment: I've put an example in the question. While it doesn't exactly relate to my original rationalization for `@closevoter, it still is another valid place where it would be useful.