# What to do after a well-deserved downvote (after editing to fix)?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, alerts

I was downvoted correctly on [an answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157704/python-intersection-between-a-list-and-keys-of-a-dictionary/11157793#11157793) that lacked some key information. I made the appropriate edit and left a comment explaining that I had edited the answer. I'm not begrudging the original downvote, but I was wondering what (if anything) can I do further in order to ensure that, if my answer is better and merits removal of the downvote, such removal takes place (assuming the downvoter would otherwise be interested)?

If there isn't anything like that, I'm wondering if it's worth thinking about? Coming from the other side, I've also been in a position where I downvoted an answer but told them exactly what was wrong, and then my goal would be to change the downvote to an upvote when the answer was fixed. Is it possible to "subscribe" to an answer as it is edited so that I can be alerted when the answer is fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're already doing the right thing from a community contribution perspective by aknowledging that your answer was incorrect, correcting your answer, and keeping a smile on your face. This is the best possible reaction for all concerned.

In order to encourage the removal of the downvote, the best practice would be to leave a comment on the answer, pinging the @user who downvoted (if they revealed themselves to you in a comment of their own when they downvoted).

If you're lucky the user will then return and re-review. However they're not under any obligation to remove their downvote or to convert it to an upvote - and they might not even come back for another look! In which case, don't worry about it, and move on: other users will now hopefully upvote your answer if it's correct, and over time the situation will rectify itself.

If the downvoting user chose to remain anonymous, there's nothing you can do except hope they come back for another look. Again, don't worry about it - and move on.

There's no way to "subscribe" to an answer - the closest you can come to this is to favourite the question (by clicking the star icon next to it) and keep track of answers manually.

Answer (score 3):

Providing the user who downvoted left a comment on your post, you can `@` reply him to say you've fixed the post. It's likely they'll revert the downvote.

If they haven't left a comment, there's no way to notify them. Feature requests exist to [notify downvoters once the post is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c), or to be able to [communicate with downvoters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post?lq=1) via a reply like `@downvoter:`.

The best thing you can do is to up-vote those feature requests to give it your support.