# Address the downvoter

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Feature request: @Downvoter sends a notification to all downvoters for your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post)

Is it possible to address the downvoter in a comment like `@downvoter`? As some people vote down and then refuse to give feedback, this could really come in handy, I think.
Is something like this possible?

P.S. tagged it as feature-request because if it isn't possible it is one.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: This has been declined before, see the linked question.

Comment: Next time you get downvoted, just imagine someone is saying: why didn't you search before asking? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan While funny, it doesn't apply as often to answers as to questions.

Comment: But I did this time! @Arjan

Comment: But on Stackoverflow... Didn't saw I had down votes on this question when I wrote my previous comment... Haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. There may be more than one downvoter (in particular over the lifetime of the post) - which one would you be addressing? The last one? All of them?

People are under no obligation to explain *why* they downvote. Some do.

Comment: The last one, I think. Can accept in 6 mins.

Comment: Forgot to accept! Sorry!