# Having a way to anonymously contact a downvoter

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, voting, down-votes

When connecting on SO this morning, I was informed that one of my old answers got a downvote.

What happened was that the original question was **incorrectly** edited and the tag `c++` was removed from the question, changing the author's original intent and making my answer suddenly off-topic. Then, I assume someone went by that question and saw my now-incorrect answer and "rightfully" downvoted it.

The downvoter is not to blame in this situation: he just saw a question with a `c` tag, saw an answer adressing the problem in `c++` and downvoted it. I don't expect anybody to check a question's edit history before voting on it. Now the question original tags have been restored, but the "damage" is done.

It's really not a big deal and this `-2` won't make my day any worse: I'm merely telling this story to provide some context to my request.

I know it was often requested that one might be able to see who downvotes to have a chance to explain or fix an answer. What I'm asking here is a bit different:

Wouldn't it be useful to be able to contact the last downvoter(s) on a question or an answer (using something like `@[downvoters]` or `@[last-downvoter]` perhaps) ?

I'm not suggesting that their identity be revealed, just that one has some way of contacting them or letting them now a fix was made to the question.

In such a situation, the "summoned" downvoter might chose to answer anonymously if he wishes so (to avoid revenge-downvotes) to give a chance to the poster to fix what was wrong.

I'm only suggesting that we allow anonymous comments on questions **in response** to the downvoted person's protest.

Having such a way of contacting a downvoter in my situation, the following could have happened:

- The downvoter would just have not cared and dismissed my notification.
- The downvoter might have looked closer at the question and saw his downvote was incorrect, cancelling it.
- He might have given another explanation of why he downvoted, possibly anonymously, giving me a chance to fix or remove the answer.

What do you think about such a feature ?

Comment: Please no. I don't care to be pinged each time I downvote something. Downvotes happen. You've probably identified the reason. Roll back the incorrect edit if you want and move on.

Comment: @Bart: What is the ability to be contacted back was a choice of the downvoter ? (But then I assume those who would chose to be contacted would likely be the ones giving an explanation right away.)

Comment: That would make the whole feature rather pointless and (I would assume) largely unused.

Comment: @Bart: Fair point I guess. What about limiting it to answers that have a strictly-positive score before the downvotes ? That is, when the downvote expresses a disagreement with some other user that found it useful.

Comment: No matter how you're going to construct this, I think that ultimately the whole "justification for a downvote" idea is not going to work. Those who find a need to make their reasoning clear to you will already do so. And those who don't care, won't really care when pinged either. Not to mention the not-so-polite situations it might cause. I don't really see a need for it all. Just shrug it off. As is the case with sh*t, downvotes happen. ;)

Comment: Another day, another suggestion that points to the same problem: you won't know why they downvoted if they don't leave a comment and even if you fix the error no one really care. I totally support you - actually I have tried to support many similar proposal in the past. What I have learned however is that many user feel like they are entitled to never explain they downvote if they don't feel like it, nor that they should really care to see if someone actually fix the answer they downvoted (or shows they are **plain wrong**). So I belive that most people would just ignore the message.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: Well, that is sadly right I guess. Perhaps I'm overestimating the number of users that would care about removing or explaining their downvotes.

Comment: The down-voter wouldn't be able to change their vote, surely?

Comment: @deadly: If the question or answer was fixed recently, I believe voters can already change their vote if they wish so. They might also be allowed to do so for a short amount of time whenever they got "pinged back" by the downvoted person.

Comment: To be clearer: problem isn't that users aren't aware of your change (I belive there is already some feedback when the answer/question is edited, but I may be wrong. Not that it couldn't be added easly...). Problem is that they feel they have exausted their "gift to umanity" when they clicked the downvote button. They don't care to tell you why. They don't care to have it fixed. So untill you find a way to change that, no other action will bring them to actually help **FIXING** bad content (because **fix** is the final goal IMHO).

Comment: @deadly - can confirm that the vote CAN be changed after an edit. I actually have experience of this. One of my answer was downvoted - I asked why, the downvoter explained his point, we worked to fix it and then he changed his vote. That should be the goal - at last in my view - fix the content or at last explain why it is wrong (I cannot read people mind, so if I see a -1 on an answer and no explanation I cannot know if the user was using his brain or his trolling powers when downvoting) so people reading may decide what to do. A number won't help me decide, unless the -1 is actually -10.

Comment: PS: also consider that if you don't have the privilege to see split vote you may even not be able to know that an answer has downvotes. Consider a +2/-1 situation - you will just see +1. And on some site with very low traffic +1 is not a bad score, nor a score that give you the feelling the answer is wrong.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I was referring to the suggestion that a down-vote on an answer can be changed if the question is edited, which is not possible as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @deadly As soon as a post is edited, the votes on that post are no longer locked and can be changed.

Comment: @ereOn However a vote cannot be changed on an answer if only the question is edited, right?

Comment: @Bart Yes, for that specific post, but not on an *answer* if the *question* is edited. Is that not the case?

Comment: @deadly I believe that is correct, yes.

Comment: I like this idea, since in this case down voter is anonymous, and the poster can get the message across. Eventually what we want is quality posts and answers, and if some poster want to improve their posters after it has been down voted, this might help them identify the problem with it. It is not about reputation, but about the quality of post, and we should give every chance to help the poster identifies what is wrong with the post at a particular moment.

Comment: @deadly - sorry. Now I got what you where pointing to. Yea... that's lame too. Especially for chamaleon/ninja/venusian shapeshifter questions.

Comment: Also we already have many "@downvoter care to comment" kind of comments  in this site..

Comment: Just what I was talking about... The "Bah, humbug! I shouldn't be entitled to help if I don't want to - I am already giving my time free of charge when I press the downvote button". Now, if someone actually cared to help improving what he sees as wrong without beging forced to we won't see so many calls for comments... But why spend your strength when you can click and move onwards?

Comment: I can envision receiving many `@Downvoter You suck!` messages. Don't want those.

Comment: @BoPersson Report them and you will see that such people will start to... just disappear... And if they are of such nature, we would only do a favor to the comunity by nuking them.

Comment: @SP - I have solved the problem by not leaving comments with by downvotes (unless I recognize the poster).  Much easier.

Comment: @BoPersson - And so no one will know what you think they should improve. Yes, that will make your vote *so usefull*. Don't take me wrong, but unless the reason is water clear (the poster decided to post a procedure that will corrupt your SharePoint farm to a question that asked hot to change a page title) a vote without comment won't do any good. Unless it is in company of another 10 little friends, which will still only prove something is wrong - not what is wrong. Now, just immagine if you asked that question and now the only answer seems to hide some dark, lurkning risk that may bite you...

Comment: @SP - I see you haven't been on main SO that much. Things are different there. In my experience, a lot of people don't  feel a need to improve, but prefer to take any problems out on the stupid downvoter. That's why we have anonymous votes.

Comment: @BoPersson: I agree that most of the users will just never fix anything anyway. But what for the minority that does ?

Comment: @BoPersson Don't know on Stack, but we have the opposite problem on SharePoint exchange. Since as soon as you put your foot outside the blood red road that Ms defined you aren't never sure that your solution doesn't cause some obscure bug (I have see the SPDialog popup missbehave if the site url use alternate mapping and the query string use a specific **CASING**) - belive me when I say that getting a -1 without comment after the 2up you may get if luky really leaves you wondering if HE knows something or is just the usual lame troll. Eeek, if you know something I don't I WANT to learn.

Comment: @ereon - I can just feel sorry for those. I did leave comment with downvotes for the first couple of months at SO, but found it not productive. My inbox was almost always full of "Is good too, stupid downvoter!" type messages. Didn't exactly encourage me to continue. Now I try to interact with people I believe is interested in hints on improving their posts, and avoid unknown posters and those that used to fill my inbox.

Comment: Same experience with @BoPersson. Always explained my downvotes the first couple of months, but at some point I just got tired of the impolite (and often outright offensive) responses.

Comment: @Yannis - If they are offensive...Such people should be nuked. Leave them a flag present - they will avoid such behaviour in the future. **IF** they will still have a future. You are only playing their game if you let them live to troll others.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Yeah, right. I'm very well aware of the process, I've handled tons of offensive flags on Programmers and suspended quite a few jerks. That's not the point though, the point is that the vast majority of people that say they'd appreciate constructive criticism on their posts are lying. Blatantly. And that's a game I'm not interested in playing, even if it means that an extremely small minority of users will have a bad experience with a misplaced downvote (or two).

Comment: @Yannis - it is not a missplaced downvote that I fear. It is a vote that I don't understand. Since I tend to propose in answers solution that I will use too, I fear the "This will backfire on you but I won't tell you why" attitude.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Feature request: @Downvoter sends a notification to all downvoters for your post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post)

Comment: I find an interesting common chord among all people against this: lack of accountability! The message seems to be *I like to slam and move on. If my down-vote is contestable or incorrect, I would rather not hear of it. Don't bother me just because I bothered you!*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your suggestion of a ping to `@[downvoters]` is not a good idea for the same reasons for any message that notifies multiple users: the potential for spam, and added noise.

This suggestion seems to be aimed at a very specific situation where a question is edited and an answerer wants a voter to change a vote on their answer. In other situations it would just be noise.

(As I pointed out in the comments, this wouldn't be very useful as the voter wouldn't be able to change their vote unless the answer was also edited. You did also suggest allowing this to happen in the comments.)

I am a little more ambivalent to your other suggestion of a ping to `@[last-downvoter]`. Mainly it seems to be of limited use but also has the potential for abuse as it can be used to badger down-voters into some response. If they're not good "citizens" anyway, they're unlikely to pay much attention so it would not help for situations outside this one.

Comment: I think you, and the other people in the comments indeed make a very good point that the feature could be a cause for too much noise and would only benefit to a minority. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: accountability is a good thing. I've seen too many examples of new users with worthwhile posts getting slammed frivolously.