# Notification on edit of down voted post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: “I think I've fixed the issue now - please check”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-ch)

Could we have a notification to the user who down voted a post if that post is edited? This way, they'll be able to consider whether they should revoke that down vote (and even turn it into an up vote!).