# How can Meta be made more conducive to discussions?

Tags: discussion, meta

<sub>Disclaimer: This post is quite lenghty. To prevent out of context interpretations I kindly request either reading it in its entirety or not reading it at all. Thank you.</sub>

### Why am I writing this?

I've been active on the Stack Exchange (SE) network for over a year [on a wide variety of different sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157047/steven-jeuris?tab=accounts). The best way to sum up my experience of SE is: *"I love it! It's the best there is."* I believe strongly in the network and it's goal of *"making the internet a better place"*, borrowing [a catchphrase](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) [of](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/10/windows-live-writer-making-the-internet-a-better-place.html) [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/farewell-stack-exchange.html). Judging [from my first SE account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590790/steven-jeuris) I have visited the network 340 days at this time, making me believe I sufficiently grasp what it is about, and know about its weaknesses and strengths. Apparently others seem to agree as [I've recently been appointed Pro-Tem moderator.](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/q/163/21) Surely I've still got much to learn, especially with those newly added responsibilities.

I am giving you this background since I find when similar discussions arise all too often people reach to the easy conclusion that a user must not grasp what a site (or meta) is about. I implore you not to place me in that category. If a user befitting my profile isn't able to understand and participate in meta, we have worse problems than the points I'll be making in this post.

This post is intended to point out what I find to be a *big* problem of the network, which is actively hurting the site. I want to address this problem *not* because I am being anarchistic, but because I strongly value the network as mentioned earlier.

### What is a discussion?

Prior to explaining why I feel meta is extremely ill-fit to host discussions, let me first define what a discussion is. [Taken from dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discussion).

> an act or instance of discussing;  **consideration or examination by
> argument**, comment, etc., especially to explore solutions; informal
> debate.

The meta tag labels it as:

> A tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or
> wrong answer and are often subjective. If it's not a bug or
> feature-request, it is probably a discussion.

In order to have a [**rational**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationality) discussion, I find the following [seemingly popular](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=667&q=what%20is%20a%20discussion?&btnG=Google%20Search&oq=comining%20flex%20and%20flash&aq=f&aqi=g-jl1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=417l5113l0l5278l27l21l3l0l0l0l255l2226l8.8.1l17#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=rational%20discussion&pbx=1&oq=rational%20discussion&aq=f&aqi=g3g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=251549l253308l0l253589l19l12l0l6l6l1l229l1557l5.6.1l17l0&gs_l=serp.3..0l3j0i15.251549l253308l0l253589l19l12l0l6l6l1l229l1557l5j6j1l17l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=89c23c73c73127de&biw=1366&bih=667) infographic particularly informing.

[image: constructive discussion inforgraphic]

### What's wrong with discussion on meta?

The [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag is one of the tags between which you *have* to choose. The other three possible tags all suit the Q&A format very nicely, with the possible exception of [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) which can often also lead to extensive discussions.

[image: required meta tags]

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is a bit of an oddball, and the SE network [was never designed with discussion in mind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124525/157047), as [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) kindly summarized.

> ...
>
> But there are two aspects that are... Just plain hard to understand
> for those unfamiliar with the site because of how it was shoehorned
> into the SE format: **discussion** and **voting**.
>
> Discussion, with two-level threading, is handled by answers and
> comments. It's not perfect - if you end up going back and forth with
> someone for more than a few rounds, it falls apart badly. Fortunately,
> we have chat to serve the need for lengthy conversations.
>
> The problem with voting is more subtle though. See, the engine already
> supported voting. It just didn't mean quite the same thing:
>
> ...
>
> - Discussion is anarchy. Maybe it's a feature-request where the details
>   haven't quite been hashed out yet. Maybe it's a rant, or a straw-poll,
>   or a short article or announcement. Voting is done according to
>   whatever arbitrary criteria the voter feels appropriate.
>
> ...

There is no denying discussion on meta is somewhat broken. If you acknowledge the intentions behind [the "don't ask" faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) on main sites, it's easy to see how the same problems apply to discussions on meta.

### Why isn't chat an alternative?

Often it is mentioned chat is an alternative to construct discussions, as in Shog9's summary above. While it's perfectly possible to have detailed discussions in chat between open-minded people, it entails all the problems which the Q&A format of SE is actually trying to solve. It doesn't leave behind a valuable (easily accessible) resource. Starring highlights of a discussion and providing a log of them somewhat attempts to alleviate this problem, but contrasted to the artifacts the Q&A format produces this is a rather weak solution. Neither can you easily pick up on an old discussion, have an overview of what has been discussed, and what some of the conclusions were.

### What do we have now?

Right now we have a complex/unclear system which everybody tries to use to their best knowledge. It's an environment which many interpret as hostile, where many actions are interpreted ambiguously. These actions however have actual consequences, regardless of how you interpret them. Discussions with the best of intentions get down voted, sometimes burying them never to be seen again.

As far as I'm concerned we *don't have* discussions by the definition I gave. The voting system linked to discussions *encourages* many people to already opt-out at the first step of the diagram: *"Can you envision anything that will change your mind?"* To demonstrate this attitude it suffices to link [to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124516/could-we-use-a-pros-cons-list-to-format-discussion/124538#comment333822_124517) by [Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) on the latest meta discussion I started.

> Voting on Meta has worked quite well, I don't see how this could
> improve it. I see what you're getting at, and the hour+ it would take
> me to go through an entire list without simply saying 'No, oh no,
> please no!" would basically prevent me from participating at all.

### Why isn't *the possibility* of influencing moderators and staff enough?

[Robert Harvey's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124650/157047) gave very valuable feedback on this post, which I find important to incorporate at this point:

> Regardless of the polarization you sometimes see here on Meta, **the
> discussion that takes place here does have an influence over the
> moderators and staff. We do listen.** Meta is the primary vehicle by
> which the mods assess the temperature of the community, and it is the
> primary mechanism by which they get detailed feedback about their
> decisions.

Or by example as [per Conrad Frix's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124643/how-can-meta-be-made-more-conducive-to-discussions#comment334658_124643), [sometimes controversial ideas do get implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111256/157047).

Unfortunately, that is *not enough*, of which his next paragraph is a nice example:

> The real tragedy are those people who stop participating in the
> discussion process because they feel that SE is ruled by elitists, and
> then raise a stink here a year later when things change in a way that
> they don't like.

I don't know whether it was intended as such, but I interpret that as an argument *for* my cause. The entire premise is we should allow discussions to take place in a more constructive format, making Meta a more hospitable environment, preventing the discourse from becoming inflammatory and uncivil. An attitude as [*"That's an inherent problem with any type of discussion or meeting, though, probably not something that we can solve over at SE."*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124643/how-can-meta-be-made-more-conducive-to-discussions#comment334633_124650) doesn't get us anywhere towards this goal. Give SE some credit, take a look back and see what you've been able to establish!

Whether or not influence is possible is besides the point. (although highly appreciated, thank you!) Wouldn't it be nice to have a *bigger* community which feels they *can* contribute, so that more *good* (constructive) stuff can reach the moderators and staff?

### What should we do?

The [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag has been used 12,143 times at the time of writing. It's an important part of the ecosystem of meta.

1. First of all I want to raise awareness (as by this post), that there *is* a problem. We are driving people away who only have the best intentions for the network.
2. A [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) isn't a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and there should be a clear difference. All too often a discussion is down voted as if it were a feature request.
3. Ideally you can't vote on discussions. You can't agree or disagree on a discussion in any way, you agree or disagree with a certain part of a discussion, preferably motivating why.
4. Stay open minded. A discussion is *meant* to raise questions. [Don't let the first question you raise shade your judgement in the rest of the discussion](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/117/21).

Comment: Damn, I just read the small text, now I need to read the whole thing!

Comment: I did read the whole thing.  I agree with much of the diagnosis, but I didn't see much in the way of concrete suggestions that SE could implement to help fix it.  Your only main suggestions were to tweak the meta tagging, and eliminate voting.  Is there something bigger SE should do?

Comment: @AdamRackis That was my original intent: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124516/157047

Comment: @Steven - ah, sorry.  I should have read *that post* too.  I don't think it's a bad idea, but might be tricky to implement.  Plus, as you well know, people don't like change :)

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - of course.  My point was that I was expecting an idea from the post as to how to fix it.  But as Steven pointed out, that was in a previous post I failed to see.

Comment: @slhck: Haha, it took some time before somebody noticed I labeled this as [meta-tag:bug]. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the Q&A format really suited for Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52521/is-the-qa-format-really-suited-for-meta), [Is the Q&A format of metas suitable for discussion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99247/is-the-qa-format-of-metas-suitable-for-discussion), and some others I can't find, perhaps they were deleted during the purge after the last Great Debate (over comment @replies)...

Comment: You don't feel that you can disagree with a discussion on the basis that its very premise is invalid? For instance, a discussion about why the sky is green, where the premise that the sky actually is green is untrue. I do get where you're coming from, but I think the larger issue is that people rarely post discussions; they post highly polarized opinions...which unfortunately tend to descend into chaos.

Comment: Also, I think most people (for whatever reason, right or wrong) tend to assume that the discussion is the means to some end, which is why some discussions, especially ones with implementation examples [such as yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124516/157047), tend to be viewed as feature-request-ish in nature.

Comment: Why do you think "it's futile and a waste of time for me and you to continue discussing controversial ideas" Sometimes they [do get implmented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111256/should-moderator-election-rules-be-changed)

Comment: @TimStone: _"an act or instance of discussing; consideration or examination by argument, comment, etc., **especially to explore solutions**; informal debate."_

Comment: I don't really get the feeling that my contributions are unvalued. Are you still getting this feeling?

Comment: Can't resist: being concise might be more conducive to discussion :)

Comment: @Benjol Funny you should say that. I totally agree, and it's what I'm striving for. As in the diagram above: _"Do not introduce new arguments while another argument has yet to be resolved."_ But that just doesn't work on meta as is. _" if you end up going back and forth with someone for more than a few rounds, it falls apart badly."_ I've made this post long _on purpose_, incorporating everything I could think of, to give it a fighting chance of staying afloat.

Comment: @CodyGray Obviously I wouldn't have written this post if didn't feel I could contribute in _some_ way. That was poor wording on my part [as pointed out by Robert Harvey](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124650/157047), and I feel [my edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/124643/revisions) improved on that. But let's put this in perspective and see the amount of effort _I_ put into this discussion, and how the community received it. I find the disproportion striking. A discussion should be balanced with equal input from both sides, not one person having to fight off an entire army.

Comment: @CodyGray As an example of _"how the community received it"_: this discussion got closed as a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52521/is-the-qa-format-really-suited-for-meta). I believe [you were part of it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124643/how-can-meta-be-made-more-conducive-to-discussions#comment334631_124643). Do _you_ feel I would have made the same impact if I'd left this post as an answer on the 'duplicate' post?

Comment: I stand by my statement that Meta is _not_ conducive for discussions, and you need to have _a lot_ of knowledge about Meta for your message to be heard.

Comment: Yes, I definitely think you would have. I think you would have made *more* of an impact. For whatever reason, people have it in their minds that it's better to post a new question, rather than answering a duplicate. I don't know where that comes from or why they're so insistent. You're not the first to act like I'm denying some special right in voting to close a question. It's like, well yeah, I *could* do that, but *you know* this is better. No, I don't. I think it's worse. It fractures debate and makes things hard to follow. Yes, knowledge of the forum is required. That's not unique to Meta.

Comment: @CodyGray _"Discussions with the best of intentions get down voted, sometimes burying them never to be seen again."_ It is my belief answering on an already down voted question, _agreeing_ with it results in more than usual down votes due to reason I explained in point 4. [_"Don't let the first question you raise shade your judgement in the rest of the discussion."_](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/117/do-people-have-a-tendency-to-stick-to-one-opinion-after-they-formed-it) If Meta _worked_ I wouldn't mind one bit answering this there.

Comment: Downvotes don't bury things never to be seen again. The algorithm is different on Meta that it is on the main site. Moreover, adding a new answer will bump a question back up to the top so that it *will* be seen again. It's frustrating when people come to Meta and post labored complaints about "the way things is" without taking time to familiarize themselves with how things actually are. Yes, if you post an agreeable answer to a question that the majority of people have downvoted because they disagree with, then it's likely your answer will be downvoted. That's not a conspiracy.

Comment: Moreover, the conclusion of the analysis in the linked question seems to indicate that group decision-making simply doesn't work, rather than that there is something uniquely wrong with the Meta format. Sunstein can be interpreted to draw a very similar conclusion regarding democracy. I've written exactly such a term paper before. I don't see how that's constructive. You're claiming that people aren't open-minded enough for the system to work while ironically not being open-minded enough to ever try and understand the system in place.

Comment: @CodyGray: _"Downvotes don't bury things never to be seen again."_ Sorry, that was an exaggerated figure of speech, by which I'm trying to say it gets seen a lot less in comparison. Remember I was argumenting why this way it has _more_ impact. It's not only the front page. The very nature of the sequential arrangement "Question, Highly up voted question, neutral question, down voted question", results in people not reading a down voted answer. ... Which of course is a _good_ thing for Q&A.

Comment: @CodyGray _"It's frustrating when people ... taking time to familiarize themselves with how things actually are."_ I've asked you not to place me in that category for a reason. It's not an argument, it's a defense system which is used all too often. Try sticking to facts, I feel you did address other interesting points.

Comment: _"The algorithm is different on Meta that it is on the main site."_ It [seems to take -8 votes for a question on meta to prevent from being bumped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117120/157047). A single post isn't evidence, but [the post which led my to write this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124516/157047) only has 223 views, vs. 344 here. I _am_ basing myself on personal experience. I also recall _before_ linking to it, that post had less than -8. I recall often seeing -8.

Comment: As regarding to the psychology question I linked to, [please read past the first paragraph](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/117/do-people-have-a-tendency-to-stick-to-one-opinion-after-they-formed-it#comment144_118). Also I didn't say it's proof something is wrong with meta, I simply used it as an argument that people don't quickly change their opinions once they formed one.

Comment: @CodyGray As another example _to be_, I've kindly followed your guidelines and didn't post a duplicate this time, [but posted an answer on an existing question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124816/157047). It's still on the front page for the time being, but let's see what happens. I believe I've done my work, the ball is in your court again. :)

Comment: @Steven: Ah, yes. Coincidentally, I just saw that answer and upvoted it *before* reading your comment. You can't judge the efficacy of Meta based on whether or not your proposed changes get implemented or not. That doesn't say whether it's conducive to discussion, that just measures the likelihood of the developers listening to feature requests from the community. They tend to listen with regard to the big picture, but not necessarily with regard to individual proposals. Jeff definitely did what he thought was best, not sure if that will change with new leadership.

Comment: _"That doesn't say whether it's conducive to discussion"_ Good point. If I've gotten anything out of all the past Meta and chat discussions, it is that the first argument I will need to strengthen is that the current way the system works, it _does_ have a measureable impact on the productivity of discussions, as to counter the "meta works just fine, there is no need to discuss this" argument. I don't think some of the more subjective argumentations I use will ever work at the moment. Do you feel this would be a worthwhile path to explore?

Comment: Is there a **TL;DR**? After the inital, "Either spend 10 minutes reading this post, or don't read it at all", I decided for the latter.  Essentially: What is the point you're trying to make?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker _"Discussions aren't Q&A"_ You might be better off [reading the answer I accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124710/157047). ;p

Comment: Related feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135384/improve-community-participation-for-meta-questions-tagged-with-discussion.

Comment: related: [What is a meta for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240440/what-is-a-meta-for)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How can Meta be made more conducive to discussions?

This is simple: stop pretending Stack Exchange's Q&A system is a good format for *discussion*.

The founding idea behind SE was something really quite simple: recognition that web forums are not a good medium for Q&A. They don't solve the problems Q&A needs, and they interfere a great deal in the Q&A process. By understand the problem they wanted to solve (Q&A), they could create a system that solved exactly that specific problem.

And they were obviously very successful at this.

The problem is that with success comes idolatry and zealotry. The belief that SE's methodology is the *best* way for people to interact outside of e-mail. Many people look at SE as the pinnacle of human communication in some way, that this is the perfect system to interact with people online.

Discussion is a fundamentally different problem than Q&A. The needs of Q&A define how SE works. It's *designed* to make real, actual *discussion* as difficult as humanly possible, because discussion usually serves as a distraction from Q&A. But if the purpose actually is discussion... well, there's not much that can be done.

In order to solve this problem, we have to agree to design a system completely outside the boundaries of the SE model. Such a system would be designed to have intelligent discussions, where people can put forth their ideas and defenses/attacks of those idea.

To do that, we have to stop using the SE model.

Comment: Thank you for the reinforcement! You might see value in [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124538/157047).

Answer (score 26):

Regardless of the polarization you sometimes see here on Meta, the discussion that takes place here *does* have an influence over the moderators and staff.  *We do listen.* Meta is the primary vehicle by which the mods assess the temperature of the community, and it is the primary mechanism by which they get detailed feedback about their decisions.

The real tragedy are those people who stop participating in the discussion process because they feel that SE is ruled by elitists, and then raise a stink here a year later when things change in a way that they don't like.

Meta is a gauntlet, a crucible for ideas.  If your idea can withstand the pounding, it might be a good one. Like many other sites on the network, Meta attracts a few really good ideas, and many bad ones.  That's why there are more questions tagged `[status-declined]` than `[status-completed]`.  But the `[status-completed]` decisions are well worth the effort of getting through all the `[status-declined]`.

**See Also** 
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html

Comment: I think there are people who stop participating because the discourse becomes inflammatory and uncivil. That's the *real* tragedy. Ideally, people need to learn to make rational arguments in favor of or against specific proposals without resorting to personal insults. That's an inherent problem with any type of discussion or meeting, though, probably not something that we can solve over at SE.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out it has an influence, I might have been too negative in my post on that aspect. However, your reply does not address that the way the current system is formed it does lead to people not wanting to participate in discussions anymore, regardless of whether they have an effect or not.

Comment: I updated my question in order to incorporate this very valuable feedback, along with a more extensive argumentation on my end. You can find it under the section _"Why isn't the possibility of influencing moderators and staff enough?"_.

Comment: @CodyGray, the most inflammatory and uncivil discourse I've seen here recently comes from people who definitely *don't* consider themselves 'meta'...

Comment: @Benjol Do you have your rose-colored glasses on? :)

Comment: @CodyGray anything inflammatory and uncivil should be flagged and edited/removed, just like anywhere else on the network. If the OP is somehow implicitly saying "there is too much rudeness" then *that's what the post should say*, with examples.

Answer (score 10):

It's not at all clear what the problem is you are trying to "fix" here.

Can you explain *what the problem is* in a few sentences?

> As the system (community) works now, I am no longer inclined to participate in any "discussions". I'll stick to the part of SE that does work, Q&A, and will sheepishly uphold the established values. Not because I'm hurt, but because I feel it's futile and a waste of time for me and you to continue discussing controversial ideas in its current form.

Best I can tell, this is the underlying request, which boils down to "some of my 'controversial' suggestions have not been well received, therefore I don't want to make any more suggestions."

If you are being turned away by rudeness or incivility **that is a serious problem and that is what you should have said.** It is specifically disallowed by the FAQ and if there are identifiable patterns of rudeness or incivility we will ban users for it without the slightest hesitation. Please, **flag rudeness or incivility anywhere you see it** so that we can take action.

But if you are being turned away by the community collectively not supporting your suggestions... I'm sorry, how is this a problem? Either make different suggestions, improve the ones you already made, or decide that conceptually we've created a "car" and you've made too many "hey, this car should be more like a truck!" suggestions. If you want to drive a truck, that's not what we do here.

Comment: Not that they haven't been well received, but that it's near _impossible_ to discuss them. Yes, because I am being turned away by rudeness and incivility, which also makes me act upon it. The discussion isn't possible anymore at that point. It's not rudeness or incivility towards a person, but towards an idea. I'm not insulted personally, and I do not feel flags qualify for that. Perhaps the original title of the post was more telling, but I was required to change it: _"Why I no longer feel like having discussions on meta"_

Comment: I'm fine by not being able to drive a truck, I'm just stating that not even being able to discuss a truck, will prevent you from ever getting to know a truck. Simultaneously I feel not having a truck might have disadvantages: _"First of all I want to raise awareness (as by this post), that there is a problem. We are driving people away who only have the best intentions for the network."_

Comment: P.s. this post doesn't seem to be 'turned down' by the community, so there might be something to it? P.s.s. conciseness on similar topics as this usually get down voted on meta.

Comment: And [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125115/157047) kind of shows the problem of not even being able to discuss it. It's an honest support question. The valid answer [is buried somewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125115/where-can-i-discuss-meta/125116#comment337156_125116) in a comment on a down voted post. No way I can accept that to point out to others chat is probably the best way, _and it is_, I've been active on Tavern on the Meta and had much better results.

Comment: @steve we definitely know how trucks work. After nearly four years of this, it is rare to see someone propose a truly original idea that we haven't seen already in some form and/or already discussed. Ideas will be discussed on their own merits, but if you're regularly walking on to the lot of a car dealer and constantly explaining how they should be making a truck, you might respectfully consider that you are perhaps in the wrong place. That said, **civility to people is required 100% of the time here** but civility to *ideas*, well, the best I can do is give you my honesty. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. But just to make clear, you do now I am _not_ talking about Q&A, [but only the Meta part](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124710/157047), e.g. discussions, right? I know you perfected Q&A, I feel the same way. **Discussions _aren't_ Q&A.** That's the concise explanation you were looking for. On a more positive note, thank you for all the effort you put into this, and for still taking the time to reply here. It's much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with you that Meta is a platform ill used for discussion.

Comments are a great mechanism for this, as evidenced by the "please move to chat" messages. If people wouldn't find comments useful for cluttering StackExchange sites with conversation exchanges, which you might call "discussions", then there would be no need to encourage people to the chat rooms.

As far as votes go, they are simply a generic sign of general agreement or disagreement. In the context of questions on StackOverflow, votes show appreciation for technical expertise, or disagreement with poor grammar or formulation. (You seem to recognize this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97022/lack-of-downvoting-and-the-public-image-of-a-downvote) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79795/new-meta-users-cant-upvote-results-in-biased-opinions).) A downvote can mean a million things. Ever seen the comment "Why the downvote?" Those guys are a result of ambiguity of votes. "Gee, someone downvoted me, but I'm not sure why. I'm open to improving my post (discussion) but what did I do wrong?" Although reputation [is important](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79728/value-of-reputation), it's a byproduct of voting. Nothing more.

Bearing that in mind, when I see such a long winded post complaining about the system, it makes me doubt the seriousness of the OP. A disclaimer at the beginning of a post offers it a new level of illegitimacy.

Looking through your profile, I see that you have raised some good ideas through critical thinking. It also seems that many of those ideas have been downvoted into oblivion. Perhaps you're just frustrated with StackExchange's resistance to change?

<sup>Also, can I have your ["backing up facts" badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111074/badge-awarded-for-backing-up-facts), since I quoted you several times?</sup>

However, there is some merit to what you are saying. As you correctly state, StackExchange is designed to resist discussion. Tagging content as "discussion" invites exactly that. One size fits all doesn't work when the two positions under consideration are polar opposites and inherently exclusive.

However, realize that most forums are terrible conversation platforms as it is. It's rare, in my opinion, to see well designed "conversation software". There's not much to be improved, and so StackExchange is likely going to stick with what the community has shown to work for itself. Q&A with a little bit of votes.

Stick around meta, it would be a shame to see you go. Perhaps you can have a positive influence in the future. I say, cut the trolling and start polling!

Comment: I'm not sure I've _ever_ seen a comment thread _in meta_ get move to chat... #justsayin

Comment: "Comments are a great mechanism for this, as evidenced by the "please move to chat" messages." Time once was we said that *forums* were a great mechanism for Q&A. We were wrong. Chat and comments are both very limited. It's like trying to discuss something while being punched in the gut; you can only speak 600 letters at a time. You have to keep everything brief, and there's no way to edit it for clarity afterwards. It's too immediate to have a real discussion.

Answer (score 5):

The premise of your question is the graphic, and the graphic strikes me as a bit of a self-parody. It pretends that there are universal, objective, criteria for facts and behaviors. And in very limited, artificial, arenas of discourse, that might be true.

However, meta is all about human behavior, and 'reasonable' is not an objective predicate. Neither is 'faulty.'

The whole premise of the graphic is that some superior intellect (the 'me' of the graphic), in a position of power, is laying out the rules of audience. If he/she deigns to talk to a mere worm, the worm has to follow the rules, and the superior mortal judges compliance.

If anyone tried to pull that shit on me I'd just walk away. In a large, amorphous, group of peers, there isn't even anyone who can claim the place of that omniscient, asinine, narrator.

I'm sure you meant well, but is that voice really a point of view you want to be associated with?

Answer (score 5):

> There is no denying discussion on meta is somewhat broken.

To the extent that, when a discussion goes off the rails (takes any rightward branch in your flowchart) Meta's discussion format tends to fall apart, **yes.**

Of course, there isn't a bit of software yet written that solves that problem. Pure discussion-focused systems (various forums and newsgroups) attempt to mitigate these failures in various ways, but since the failures occur on the part of one or more *participants* in the discussion, they cannot be solved completely by technical measures (most of which amount to some form of auto-silencing those who appear to participate in bad faith).

Meta discussion doesn't really even try. There's very little value to us in keeping a detailed historical record of every discussion that falls apart because of an unwillingness on the part of participants to stick to that left-hand flow. So when a discussion falls apart, it tends to get down-voted, closed, and eventually deleted. We're not even looking to maintain a chronological record of discussions that *do* work; maintaining just the arguments and counter-arguments is enough.

Because we're all human, and therefore *terrible* at conducting calm, rationale discussion, this often fails - and here, Chat becomes the mitigating factor. But chat is not intended to be a historical record. Once you've worked out whatever factors led to problems in chat, you must take the results back to Meta.

Does this confuse people? Drive them away? Heck yeah! So does the pure Q&A format of Stack Overflow - by nature, most people are as unwilling or unable to formulate a good question as they are to kick off and participate in productive discussion, and by requiring them to do so we absolutely alienate quite a few potential participants.

But for those that are willing to learn and participate in our weird little system, the payoff is huge: instead of the traditional "dozens of messages each containing a small piece of the answer", there's a clear path from specific question to specific answer, a useful artifact on The Internet for the education of future readers.

And the same is true for meta discussions. There's no pretense here that every potential participant's input is valuable. But if you can present a persuasive argument, defend it against reasoned criticism, and move on when you're unable to persuade others, then you'll be welcome here.

Comment: _"... present a persuasive argument, **defend it against reasoned criticism**, and move on ..."_ How do you defend it against criticism if the system as you mention _"doesn't even try"_. That's what goes wrong in my opinion, and that's what this post was about. It is probably more likely for a big player to step up and provide a platform for it, instead of continuing believing that you can 'fight' a system from the inside out. Somebody [_will_ eventually make this](http://www.proconlists.com/), and here I was just hoping it would be SE.

Comment: @Steven but *why* should SE do this? Pro/con lists and discussions are hardly part of its core business... plus I think your accusation that "the system doesn't even try" is starting to get ridiculous. A number of users (myself included) has seriously thought about your ideas over the past couple of days, agreed to some of them, and reasonedly criticized others. They haven't been received well by the community in terms of total number of votes, but you can't complain about lack of attention.

Comment: As much as I appreciated your input Pekka, from my point of view (e.g. with the topics I raise) you're the minority. As to _why_ should SE do this? Because SE has gotten bigger than Q&A. Discussion (Meta, our very being here) has _become_ a part of SE.

Comment: @Steven: the system doesn't try very hard to solve social issues with technical measures. We depend on folks participating here because they care about the system this site exists to serve - the main Q&A sites. If they can't or won't participate in good faith, then we have no particular need to cater to them *at all.* If you want an answer on SO, you'll learn to ask an effective question; if you want to be taken seriously here on MSO, you'll learn to write a good argument.

Comment: A _good_ argument, or [a concise argument](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125309/157047)? Obviously I failed at both. Could you please disable my Pro-Tem Moderator access once a suitable replacement candidate has been found? It's way too tempting to end up on Meta while having to discuss moderation constantly. Obviously Meta is not for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Steven a good argument on Meta should *mostly* be a concise one. It *is* the age of [`tl;dr`]  after all :)

Comment: Being concise does tend to be useful, @Steven, but that's *almost* orthogonal. I would say being *focused* is more important here, whether that means one paragraph, or five pages. Your recent posts suffer from trying to address too many issues simultaneously - when your first goal *must* be to convince readers that the problem actually *exists*, this is a recipe for failure: you can't spend enough time on any one issue to do it justice.

Comment: @Pekka I'm afraid so.

Comment: @Shog9 This post is meant to convince readers that the problem exists. They reply, "it doesn't because it works". That's a concise argument alright, except that it isn't. After dozens of discussions, I realize [I should ask _how_ I _could_ convince them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125055/157047). Read, step 1 of a discussion, being open to being convinced. My conclusion is they obviously don't want to be convinced, and definitely not through Meta. So I took the conversation to chat. I might linger around there, but I really don't see how I can be more focused.

Comment: @Steven: there *again*, you struggle to focus on any one thing. Participation? That's a huge topic all on its own - I can give you hard numbers on participation here relative to SO, but first we need to establish what sort of participation we should be measuring on *either* site. Efficiency? *Should* that even be a goal? If so, efficiency for what... or for *whom?* Satisfaction may or may not depend on either of the first two factors, and will almost certainly vary based on what each person's goal is. These are huge, thorny topics, and you're running at them at full speed, eyes closed.

Comment: @Shog9, the point was to ask for _any_ metric. It was deliberately (but as you stated possibly not smart) broad. _"I believe that the best way to see **which metrics could be used to resolve the argument "Meta works"** is by posting a suggested metric per answer. Up vote those metrics which you feel would be a good representation, down vote those you find to be too subjective or irrelevant."_

Comment: It was my intent to address as you put it: _"first we need to establish what sort of participation we should be measuring on either site."_, etc ...

Comment: For now I'm just leaving Meta, as I tried my best, and obviously I'm not qualified to be addressing these issues (if they even need to be addressed). I get annoyed by them too much to stay around here. It's what some interpret as a dictatorship, but I just interpret it as miscommunication. Once there _is_ a possibility of discussing this here, I'll gladly hear from you. I'm tracking this post as I feel it best expresses my concerns. If this doesn't attract up votes over time I have no reason to come back.