# Where can I discuss Meta?

Tags: support, meta

Searching Meta for [*"meta meta"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+meta+meta) gives me the impression [I am supposed to discuss Meta on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55/157047).

I'm having difficulties starting [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) discussions on Meta.

They have a high tendency of being:

- [Down voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124837/a-kata-for-meta-a-place-to-cool-down)
- [Closed as Not Constructive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125055/157047)
- [Misinterpreted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124516/could-we-use-a-pros-cons-list-to-format-discussion#comment333791_124516), [even](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124516/could-we-use-a-pros-cons-list-to-format-discussion#comment333797_124516) [after](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124516/could-we-use-a-pros-cons-list-to-format-discussion#comment333831_124516) [pointing out those misinterpretations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124516/could-we-use-a-pros-cons-list-to-format-discussion#comment333795_124516).
- Generally not being well received.
- And oh my, even [attract delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125056/157047)

This prevents me from discussing Meta on Meta.

Where *should* I discuss Meta?

Comment: Discussing Meta on Meta is fine. However in every discussion you need to be prepared that your arguments will not be well received and also allow for the possibility that you are completely wrong. Changing the discussion medium won't necessarily mean that people will start agreeing with you...

Comment: The answer is *not* "the meta meta chat room". Any valuable discussion should not been buried in chat. Please stop this little project of promoting your just-created chat room. Otherwise, prepare for downvotes for posting a wrong answer.

Comment: At the going rate, we'll have to build an infinite number of places to discuss what we don't like about the *n - 1* place.

Comment: @balpha Promoting my little chat room? It's a last resort to an ongoing discussion over the past week. Several users pointed out chat might be a better medium to discuss this, I listened. Please read through all my past posts if you want to start understanding how it got to this point.

Comment: _"discussions should not be buried in chat"_ Agreed, [I also argue that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124643/157047). However, bringing that forward as an argument to be able to have discussions on Meta doesn't weigh up to "Meta works".

Comment: @StevenJeuris You missed a word there: "Any **valuable** discussion should not been buried in chat". I wouldn't mind for every other discussion to be buried in chat...

Comment: @YannisRizos: Then that would be a reason for you to up vote my answer, _"We bother Meta less: we can more fully discuss ideas prior to releasing them on Meta."_

Comment: @StevenJeuris I considered upvoting for that sentence alone. However you'll need to be a little bit clearer that you propose chat as an alternative for questions that aren't valuable enough for Meta, for me to upvote.

Comment: The definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results.

Comment: @YannisRizos I'm done trying to be clear here on meta. _Clear_ is subjective. Any post _against_ meta is usually considered _not clear_ by default. _"My conclusion from personal experience is it's best to only bring forward those discussions that at least have a fighting chance"_ was an earlier statement in that answer. If you feel you can improve it, I feel you've got the gest of where I'm going with this, I'll gladly see it.

Comment: @MarkTrapp A characteristic of somebody who isn't listening to arguments brought forward in a discussion is somebody who isn't able to distinguish between different arguments brought forward.

Comment: @StevenJeuris A characteristic of somebody who isn't a masochist (or a troll) is having the self-awareness to cut their losses and realize maybe the place where they keep getting rejected isn't worth their time.

Comment: Ah, finally, someone said the t-word...

Comment: @MarkTrapp Now that I can agree on. Hence, the chat suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What about meta-meta Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 15):

> Searching Meta for [*"meta meta"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+meta+meta) gives me the impression [I am supposed to discuss Meta on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55/157047).

That is correct.

> I'm having difficulties starting [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) discussions on Meta.
>
> They have a high tendency of being:
>
> - [Down voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124837/a-kata-for-meta-a-place-to-cool-down)
> - [Closed as Not Constructive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125055/157047)
> - [Misinterpreted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124516/could-we-use-a-pros-cons-list-to-format-discussion#comment333791_124516), [even](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124516/could-we-use-a-pros-cons-list-to-format-discussion#comment333797_124516) [after](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124516/could-we-use-a-pros-cons-list-to-format-discussion#comment333831_124516) [pointing out those misinterpretations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124516/could-we-use-a-pros-cons-list-to-format-discussion#comment333795_124516).
> - Generally not being well received.
> - And oh my, even [attract delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125056/157047)

That's because people disagree with your suggestions and/or think they're unconstructive. In other words, your attempt(s) to initiate discussion are working exactly as intended. The proposals are being discussed and subsequently rejected by members of the community.

Just because you disagree with community opinion does not mean that you've chosen the wrong forum in which to initiate the discussion. I don't think any of your questions have been closed as off-topic. *That* would be the indication that you've chosen the incorrect site on which to post your question(s).

Perhaps the real problem is that so far, you've been trying to tell the Meta community that the established system simply doesn't work and needs to be radically reformed. Paradoxically, you're trying to do that *within* the very system that you claim is broken. Logically, both cannot be true simultaneously. If the system really is broken, you're not going to be able to use it to successfully effect change. If you *can* successfully effect change, then the system is *not* broken and does not need to be radically reinvented as you suggest.

Beyond that pesky little logical paradox, it is probably true that questions critical of the entire system are not likely to be well received. But that's not something limited to a Q&A site on the Internet. Attempting to resist the system from within the system is an admirable strategy, but it rarely goes over very well. You might be interested in the advice contained in the answers to this question: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: I _totally_ can't take this answer seriously, coming from a guy who wrote the following about closing a Meta discussion: [_"There's a perfectly good reason, it's even given in the close description: "this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125071/on-the-recent-deletion-discussion-process/125079#comment337072_125071)

Comment: I *totally* don't understand how those two opinions are contradictory. Nicol's argument there skips over the adjectival modifier *extended* that precedes "discussion" in the quoted explanation. Alternatively, you could strike discussion entirely from the list of possible problems: all of the rest are still true with regards to that question. I thought that "question" was unconstructive. So did 4 other members of the community. I alluded to as much in the first paragraph here.

Comment: I have a hard time believing your second-last paragraph isn't a joke.

Comment: @CodyGray: Appreciate the edit note, sorry about that. I'll post a new question on meta where we can discuss my erroneous edit, your reaction to it, and another one about how useful that post is. And then another one about how discussion of the first two might effect the community.

Comment: @Madmartigan Care to link me to it? E.g. in the Meta Meta chat room. Otherwise I might miss it when it get down voted drastically.

Answer (score -10):

You are right pointing out discussing [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) on Meta is generally not well received.

While [some people agree Meta has it's issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124643/157047), the general consensus is it's *good enough*. This is also used as the main argument of many *against* discussing this. The problem is there is [*no way* to counter this argument](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125055/157047).

My conclusion from personal experience is it's best to only bring forward those discussions that *at least* have a fighting chance, otherwise you will only get frustrated in seeing them being closed.

However! We are lucky Stack Exchange has provided us with an alternative, chat! I created the [Meta Meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/479/meta-meta) chatroom as a place for us meta meta people to go ahead discussing Meta.

It has a few advantages:

- They can't close it.
- There is a lower signal to noise ratio.
- We bother Meta less: we can more fully discuss ideas prior to releasing them on Meta.

Comment: Notwithstanding the discussions in the comments on the question, regarding your bullet points: 1) Chat rooms can be frozen, which is analog to closing a question. 2) is very true, but I fail to see how a lower SNR is benefitial. 3) Is true, and already happens; feel free to create rooms for discussing prior to posting on Meta, or drop into the Tavern.

Comment: Thank you for the _relevant_ feedback!

Comment: @balpha Actually, consider adding that as an answer instead. If this works out for me, and I don't see any problems with it, you made your point, and it answers my support question as easy as 'Tavern on the Meta'. Thank you.