# Are the height and width for all Stack Exchange sites the same?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, design

Recently, I update my about page from Stack Overflow and synchronize with all Stack Exchange sites. But when I look at my a few different profiles, about pages' width and / or heights don't look equal. Let me show you a few examples;

From [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-gonul);

[image]

From [Meta.Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158761/soner-gonul)

[image]

From [Poker.Stackexchange](https://poker.stackexchange.com/users/445/soner-gonul)

[image]

From [Movies.Stackexchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1992/soner-gonul)

[image]

For first paragraph, Stack Overflow and Meta looks similar but Poker.SE and Movies.SE are different from them. This could be because of the design of tag icons; the first two sites' icons are look like rectangles but the others look like ellipses.

For the second red lines, why does the sentence fit onto a single in Stack Overflow and Meta but require two line in Poker.SE and Movies.SE? Aren't all SE sites' about pages width and height properties equal?

Comment: [Downvotes mean something different on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126590/do-downvotes-on-meta-truly-mean-something-different)

Comment: Asking for comments on downvotes are considered noise, as it's not directed at anyone (no one receives an inbox notification when you make that comment).  Comments that are considered noise are generally deleted.  This applies for *all* sites in the Stack Exchange network, and their metas.  If people *do* comment, it's a nicety, but should not be expected or asked for.

Comment: @casperOne there is **no stated rule** that one cannot comment asking why there were downvotes. I have never seen it as noise, some people are generally curious, and if someone sees the comment of "Why the downvote..." etc, they can comment back to the OP.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA This has been touched on *many* times; the system nags you to leave a comment depending on reputation and whatnot.  If the *system* nags you to do this, then *you shouldn't* be doing this.

Comment: @casperOne the system never has nagged me... unless I was missing something.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Probably because you're way past the rep requirement when it was implemented.  Earn 125 rep on any other Stack Exchange site and then cast a downvote and see what happens.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA [And here's the feature request that was implemented that nags the user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/140951).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Stack Overflow theme uses the font family `Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif`, while the beta site theme uses the font family `'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif`. You likely have that Helvetica font installed on your system, which is causing a different font to be used between the themes. As well, the container on beta sites also has a 1-pixel border on both sides plus a width 3 pixels wider than on Stack Overflow. Not huge differences, but even the smallest things can have effects like this.

Answer (score 7):

Every Stack Exchange site has it's own unique CSS that controls how it looks (unless it is a beta site, then it has the beta CSS).

So each site *might not* have the same **`width`** and `height` for every element on the page, so everything won't necessarily look the same from site to site.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting this. It's still perfectly correct, it just takes a different route at answering the question than I did...

Comment: @animuson hehe both of our answers are technically the same thing, but yet mine gets downvoted...