# Meta-discussions shouldn't encourage echo-chamber effects

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, meta

#### The Problem

Democracy is a wonderful thing, but to quote Heinlein:

> [M]ajority rule gives the ruthless strong man plenty of elbow room to oppress his fellows.

With that in mind, I want to point out that meta's current semantics for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is broken. The current system actively discourages many people from posting thoughtful (but opinionated) questions or answers to questions that don't have an objective right or wrong. That is supposed to be the *point* of the tag. The tag's wiki currently says:

> A discussion question may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and is often subjective.

However, the current ability to vote down discussions results in an echo-chamber effect. Symptoms of this include:

1. People without rep to burn tend to avoid postings that will get down-voted, especially on contentious issues with a potential for a pile-on effect.
2. People hide out in comments, criticizing others' opinions without offering anything substantive as a competing answer. Go head; I'll wait while you count the number of "You're wrong because..." comments that should really be posted as answers.
3. The loudest and most opinionated people tend to drown out other voices, and to short-circuit the possibility of discussion by aggressively down-voting differing opinions.

All of these things should be easy to fix by a community that is solutions-oriented.

#### Propose a Solution

Please propose a constructive solution if you have one. If you don't think there's a problem, and that things are perfectly fine as they are, then feel free to upvote one of the existing answers that says the status quo is great, or add your own alternative.

Downvoting this *question* just means you don't want to consider the merits of the idea, either pro or con. That is not constructive, but hey--it's your vote.

Comment: +0: I agree with the sentiment that the discussion system on MSO is broken, but I disagree with the proposed solution :(.

Comment: Obligatory answer disguised as comment stating how totally utterly completely WRONG you are: The number of comment-answers is high because if you don't have much to say, many people (me included) put it in a comment. Answers, even on meta, should _generally_ be more than 400 chars, IMO.

Comment: Btw, if this is implemented, I will [C&H roll](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134710/178438) every [discussion] post ever. Want that? ;-)

Comment: Do you have any examples of answers downvoted because they're against the grain and not because they're just trolling?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124643/how-can-meta-be-made-more-conducive-to-discussions

Comment: Meta is not only a discussion zone; it is also a voting booth. Hence voting (and especially downvoting) needs to stay. I could live with making all discussion threads auto-CW though

Comment: `The loudest and most opinionated people tend to drown out other voices` how? Do they have more than one vote because they have such loud voices? I have a very loud voice. Where can I fetch my extra votes?

Comment: -1 you're effectively butchering democracy by creating an environment where people can only agree; if someone posts a terrible or controversial answer, my only opposition would be to (non-anonymously) post a complete answer disagreeing with their posts. I shouldn't have to post a whole answer or even comment just to say "No".

Comment: @BenBrocka You just spent 328 characters and a downvote to express an opinion...but you managed to do it in a comment where no one can vote on the merits of your opinion. Please post your response as an answer to avoid "butchering democracy," and so that *I* don't have to post an answer to your answer just to say "No." kthnx.

Comment: Your wrong because...well, because of all the stuff discussed in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125071/on-the-recent-deletion-discussion-process

Comment: @BenBrocka just posted in a place where only upvotes are visible and taken and there is no other option (other than flagging) to dissent or disagree. Looks like the future system is already at work.

Comment: @random BZZZT! Sorry, but thanks for playing. He used the current system, which has all of the downsides (and none of the upsides) of *any* of the proposed systems suggested--mine or others. Saying "Ooh, look, people can be unhelpful, unconstructive, or game the system!" doesn't imply the status quo is virtuous, nor is it a reasoned comparison of the relative merits of any two systems. If people can do it *now*, then you haven't made a logical case for why an alternative would be worse--all you've done is reinforce my original argument.

Comment: You still haven't pointed out where users have been drummed out in the current system which is being labelled as broken for fostering even more discussion

Comment: @random Gee, well, since I'm not a moderator or S.O. admin, I don't actually have access to that information. Possibly you do. As counterpoint, please point me to *your* data showing that no one has ever dropped out of SO or meta as a result of the current system. **Hint:** you can't just point to the size of the user base; growth and attrition aren't at issue here, but rather your imputation that there's zero correlation between the discussion system and any churn.

Comment: @CodeGnome Moderators have access to some nifty tools, but there is a *"find drummed out users"* link that I'm aware of. Your best bet might be to troll Data Explorer for users with many net negative score and look for a activity arc. My personal experience is that we bend over backwards to tolerate really obnoxious users in the name of inclusiveness and generally not be big meanies. Take that for what you will.

Comment: @CodeGnome: "please point me to your data showing that no one has ever dropped out of SO or meta as a result of the current system." Um, why? The fact that someone, somewhere, dropped out at some point is not *a priori* bad. Sometimes, people just have really bad ideas. Some people refuse to understand what SE is all about, and will constantly propose things that will undermine the site. There is a difference between an unpopular idea and a *bad* idea. The problem is that the current method has no way to distinguish between these; unpopular means bad.

Comment: If anybody wants to post a laughably stupid discussion they want to post, and is worried about getting downvoted, please contact me.  I've got all these worthless meta rep points and I'd be happy to transfer some of them to you, as long as you give me some lols in return.

Comment: [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168) "feature like this would make it technically harder for me to post an answer. Imagine I am willing to add 20th answer to some question, that would mean I have to pass through checking 19 prior answers before posting my own, go figure..."

Answer (score 13):

> The current system actively discourages many people from posting opinionated answers to questions that don't have an objective right or wrong, which is supposed to be the point of the tag.

Nonsense.

I don't know what you're basing this assertion on, but I can only assume you have a rather convenient definition for "many" that happens to exclude the vast numbers of people who *have* and *continue to* post opinionated answers to subjective questions here on MSO.

Or... Perhaps you're trying to say, "the current system actively discourages many people from posting completely unsubstantiated opinions that add nothing to the discussion but noise" - in which case I *still* don't believe you, but... If true, **GOOD.**

There are plenty of aspects of discussion on meta sites that are less-than-optimal. IMHO, chat goes a long way toward solving many of them, but that doesn't mean there's not still room for improvement. But I *strongly* disagree that allowing people to down-vote useless opinions is a problem. Feel free to prove me wrong...

Comment: Kindly? No. Opinionated? Yes. @gdoron.

Comment: Sure, @gdoron. But that wouldn't encourage down-votes as easily then, would it... And let's face it: in this context, "I dare say you may be somewhat mistaken or perhaps even willfully ignorant in this matter" is only superficially more polite; there are a half-dozen more diplomatic answers here already... Let's cut to the chase.

Comment: @gdoron I can't believe you downvoted for that reason on this question. We're discussing the appropriate use of downvotes and that's certainly not what they're for.

Comment: -1. You mean, am I against "answers" like yours that basically assume any opinion but yours is *objectively* wrong? You bet I am...and I thank you for your post, which illustrates my point better than anything else I could imagine.

Comment: @CodeGnome: Good. I'm against them too. Now, can you explain why we would want to make any changes to [tag:discussion] that would *encourage* such answers?

Comment: Evelyn Beatrice Hall once wrote, "I disapprove of what you say, but I will defend to the death your right to say it." If the current system doesn't prevent such posts, then a new system that provides a better balance of voices is needed.

Comment: @CodeGnome I don't follow. Are you in favour of *preventing* these kinds of posts? I was under the impression you meant the opposite

Comment: @CodeGnome: perhaps you're right. To that end, how about increasing the "penalty" imposed by down-votes to 20 on [tag:discussion] posts? Or 30? At 30, I would be breaking even on this answer thus far - which seems much more appropriate.

Comment: @Pekka You misunderstood; please read it again. *Nothing* prevents bad posts, and there are plenty of tools to clean those up. My point is that the whole "bad posts" argument is a straw dog; the real issue is whether everyone should be allowed a voice, or only people who advance popular opinions.

Comment: @Code "bad" posts aren't necessarily *low quality* posts. "bad" in a Meta context means that a large number of Meta users doesn't think the idea or opinion expressed is a good thing for Stack Overflow. Meta is not really supposed to be a marketplace of ideas, it's a place to gauge how the community stands on issues. Plus, while I agree removing rep from the equation would be a good idea, your rep argument is moot. 1 upvote counters *5 downvotes*. Unless your post is complete garbage, it's *always* going to net you points.

Comment: @Pekka: There's just one problem. If you post too many things that the MSO community deems to be not a good idea, then you get answer-banned. So if you disagree too much with the community, not only do you lose rep (and therefore privileges), you also lose the chance to even give your opinion a fair hearing. The point is that unpopular opinions still need a voice.

Comment: @Pekka: "Meta is not really supposed to be a marketplace of ideas, it's a place to gauge how the community stands on issues." This post is saying that voting is *not* a good gauge of how "the community" stands on an issue, because voting *itself* prevents people from voicing their opinion. I personally have avoided giving voice to certain views because I know they would simply be ignored and down-voted. This kind of behavior creates and echo-chamber effect, such that the only voices are those that already agree with the plurality.

Comment: @Nicol That is a problem that can be solved only through personal courage, not by making the system seem nicer. You're always going to have a hard time when going against a group's consensus... that's just the way it is, and the group isn't necessarily always *wrong*. And it's not like Meta is arresting and torturing dissenting voices, it's just downvoting them, usually even with no rep loss because (as said above) if you don't post *complete* garbage, you will usually find at least one person agreeing with you. I do agree that the answer ban needs to be removed from Meta, though...

Comment: ... and real trolls dealt with in the traditional way (suspensions, etc.)

Comment: @Pekka: Why should having a hard time also include losing the right to edit posts, or post comments, or any number of other privileges? It's not about a few points of rep; it's about losing the ability to use the site in various ways (or, in the case of answer-bans, at all). Also, it's important in a democracy to *encourage* going against the consensus; that's the only way you stop it from becoming an echochamber that only accepts the prevailing opinion.

Comment: @Nicol show me a dissenting voice on Meta Stack Overflow that has actually had a net loss of reputation points, and lost their user rights, after making some constructive posts whose only fault was that they went against the mainstream opinion. As said, one upvote makes up for five downvotes. I put it to you that this supposed big rep loss caused by going against the Mainstream is a myth. If you have evidence to the contrary, show it.

Comment: @Pekka Reputation is a *proxy* for various things. The issue isn't so much about +/- rep, it's about promoting democracy in a democratic forum. You're ignoring the psychological and sociological side of this issue when you focus on rep as an end unto itself.

Comment: @Code the psychological and sociological side is that negative feedback *hurts*, and that we crave positive feedback from our peers. I get that - despite my many meta repz (which are really *entirely* worthless btw), I get frequently miffed when the community shuns an idea of mine that I think is great. But removing the negative feedback is *not the solution.* That's just creating the illusion the feedback isn't there.

Comment: Also @CodeGnome don't forget that Meta is not *really* a democracy. It's a source of impulses to the team, helps gauge opinions, and shape the community and its rules to some extent... which isn't actually that much. A vast majority of the stuff that we discuss here will never have any real-world impact, no matter how many people vote for or against something.

Comment: Everyone who downvoted this answer...think what that means if you also support the idea in the question. Food for thought.

Answer (score 12):

Downvotes *work*, even in discussion.

I just had an answer receive 2 immediate downvotes here on meta, so instead of complaining about downvoting, I decided to consider what was wrong with the post I wrote.

I decided the downvotes were telling me the answer was too harsh, and I ultimately agreed with that, so I modified my answer to be less.. strident in tone. (You can look up my recent answers to see which one it was.)

Therefore, I am glad when people downvote my posts, as it gives me an opportunity to consider how I might improve them, and why they are not seen in a favorable light by others.

Comment: While I agree that crowd-sourcing is generally a good thing--I *am* active on SO, after all--I truly think this doesn't address the issues I raised in the question. I've lost over 20 rep so far (14 at one shot--probably a moderator?) just for advancing this idea as worthy of discussion, and expect that number to go higher as people pile onto whatever the moderators answer. The downvotes in no way represent consensus (the upvotes do, perhaps), they just punish people for advancing unpopular opinions. *shrug* If that's "as-designed," well, it's always good to know where one stands.

Comment: @CodeGnome, -14 rep "at one shot" just means seven people downvoted within whatever threshhold vote events are reported -- moderators don't have more votes per post than anyone else. How can upvotes represent consensus but not downvotes? Either is an expression of opinion. A consensus can be against an idea just as much as for.

Comment: @CodeGnome no, you have actually *gained* 5 reputation points from this question - 25 points from upvotes, minus 20 points from downvotes. And you've lost me completely with your argument that downvotes are "punishment", while upvotes suggest "consensus"...

Comment: @JoshCaswell I understand from other posts on meta that moderators can vote more than once. That's sort of a side issue, though, since this issue isn't really about rep. --In a **discussion**, consensus should be *for* some articulated viewpoint, not a rejection of a viewpoint without offering an alternative.

Comment: @CodeGnome: You need to pick a different word, because "consensus" just means a summing up of opinions, for or against.

Comment: @CodeGnome moderators can not vote more than once. Re your discussion argument, maybe that's the core of our disagreement... using your definition of "discussion" on Meta sounds like a recipe for insanity.

Comment: @Josh in certain circles--such as the church I attend--"consensus" has come to mean more than that: that almost all the opinions are in at least grudging agreement (only the grumpy curmudgeon is allowed to be in dissent) and that rainbows and ponies prance about the landscape in approval of the caring and joyous process that arrived at the agreement. You are welcome to draw what every opinion you like about how *I* see this new definition.

Comment: @dmckee: Thanks, noted. O, how I love the narrowing of meaning. Rainbows and prancing ponies seem like they would make for a fun Sunday morning, at least.

Answer (score 8):

Plenty of discussion on Meta as it is. There are [20 golden badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/44/discussion) compared to the two golden badges for support.

Users without EXP to purge are also the freshest to the ecosystem and often barge in throwing their hands in the air shouting about all the ways things should be and how wrong the system and The Man are without spending any time reading and understanding why things are in the first place.

Perhaps it may seem as though only the loudest are heard it's also reflective of the fact that they've taken their chops, hit that grindstone and all other metaphors in hashing out their opinions. Downvotes add character and a bold epoxy in the face of the grain.

Take away the democratic nature of downvotes on answers in discussions and we'll just see plenty of flags pop up in the queue by those who have no other anonymous recourse to express their disagreement. Then we'll talk about hiding out.

If there was a problem to begin with in the discussions. For what it is, it's affectionately as broken and as effective as it needs to be.

Comment: And users who have been around but *still* don't have EXP to burn (like the one you've just so neatly alluded to) clearly don't get it *despite* the time they've spent.

Comment: contrary to popular belief, I don't enjoy getting downvoted either, but a community without downvotes is a community of peers unwilling to be honest with each other.

Comment: +1000000000 `Users without EXP to purge are also the freshest to the ecosystem and often barge in throwing their hands in the air shouting about all the ways things should be and how wrong the system and The Man are without spending any time reading and understanding why things are in the first place.`

Answer (score 2):

I could never be in favor of a system that allows users to gain reputation from posts they make without the worry or possibility of losing reputation for those same posts. Not only is that entirely unfair in the sense of reputation, but it would shift it to the other extreme. Users would start posting total nonsense answers in discussion questions which have no meaning just for the sake of posting them because they can't be downvoted for it.

A better solution than just preventing downvotes would be to get rid of the reputation loss for downvotes, since that seems to be why people are worried about it, but that still goes against the fairness of being able to lose reputation as well as gain reputation. So the only plausible solution would be to make discussion questions act more like a community wiki, where you can't gain or lose reputation, and I'm not sure many people would be in favor of that. Community wiki is already [mis]used on occasion to post opinions without having to worry about downvotes.

I personally think a "community wiki" mode for the discussion tag would be a fair alternative. However, you have to also consider reputation already gained from questions which were discussions. Retroactively applying changes is a huge deterrent for a lot of users. Also, flat-out labeling all of our discussions as community wikis seems a bit of a lie, because they're certainly not always community wikis in the sense we're supposed to be using them.

Comment: If *answers* got neither upvotes or downvotes, how would you measure consensus at all? Other than by polling the comments, I mean. --I agree it's a tricky issue, which is why I think we should consider all angles.

Comment: I'm not saying you couldn't upvote and downvote, I'm saying you wouldn't gain or lose reputation for either of those events. If you can't lose reputation, you shouldn't be able to gain it either.

Comment: "I'm not saying you couldn't upvote and downvote, I'm saying you wouldn't gain or lose reputation for either of those events." I like this, because one shouldn't gain or lose rep for an *opinion*. Since this would only apply to discussions, I'm giving it a +0.75 (I disagree with the community wiki part, but see your point of view regarding rep).

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with animuson on this, but I'd like to expand it a little further. You are suggesting prohibiting downvotes on the discussion tag, but that defeats the purpose of reputation. Users should never be able to gain reputation without the fear of losing it. I propose a community wiki-ish style of doing things where downvotes *as well as* upvotes don't count for reputation.

I don't know if I completely agree with declaring them community wiki, because that suggests that the answer belongs to the whole community, which isn't necessarily the case. The answer, the entire idea, still belongs to the user that posted it (but I suppose it should be open to regular editing to keep up the quality  the site demands)

Comment: The thing is that user who are worried about possible rep loss have the power to make their own answer CW now. They can even apply it after the downvotes start coming in.

Answer (score 1):

You have good reasoning for a terrible idea.

The SE Q&A system is not conducive for discussion. Indeed, I'm not sure that any up/down vote-based system is a good idea for actual discussion. It encourages people to vote based on what position they hold, rather than actually listening to well-reasoned arguments and possibly changing their mind.

There is no real way to determine victory in a discussion, or even just consensus on a topic. All you ever really get is who shouted loudest, who kept repeating their argument, who decided not to just give up and go elsewhere.

However, what you suggest is not helping. Even if you could get past the technical issues of a tag fundamentally changing the nature of how the site works, it's still terrible. Even if tagging questions were limited to moderators or something, it would still not actually solve the problem.

You aren't going to turn a Q&A engine into a discussion engine with a couple of tweaks. All you'll get is a crappy Q&A engine.

Comment: I agree with most of what you said, except for the implication that there's absolutely nothing to be done about it. I agree that the Q&A format is a poor discussion format; however, I disagree that the SO engine is in any way impacted by how we treat discussions on meta. If you don't like my suggestions, fair enough...but that shouldn't prevent people from trying to find a reasonable solution within the constraints of the system.

Comment: @code I find that the best reasoned *ideas* and *proposed solutions* tend to get upvoted here in discussions. How this is bad, I cannot see.

Comment: @JeffAtwood We're actually in agreement on the value of upvoting ideas and solutions. The question as posted has to do with downvoting *answers* to questions marked "discussion." The former builds consensus; the latter punishes people for opinions. This is a problem that is particular to the discussion tag, and not intended as a broader issue.

Comment: @CodeGnome: Upvotes to answers on questions marked [discussion] _reward_ people for opinions, completely out of proportion to the punishment of downvotes, which _also_ express opinions and thus also build consensus.

Answer (score 0):

I started writing this in a comment but I had too much to say:

I would up-vote for the quote, however, you're relying on quite a lot. (Yes I know it's always easy to find fault rather than look for positives, sorry about that.)

Firstly, I don't believe that you can forbid down-votes. It means that [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) can *never* be removed. Better that down-votes mean nothing.

However, I still don't agree with this feature request; mainly because of the definition of discussion. To quote from [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discussion):

> noun
>   an act or instance of discussing;  consideration or examination
>   by argument, comment, etc., especially to explore solutions; informal
>   debate.

Discussion implies dissenting opinion. If you forbid down-votes how do dissenting opinions get recorded and a comparison made between differing opinions? It can only be, fairly, achieved by a dissenting answer being posted. To be properly fair that answer would have to be equally argued and eloquent.

It's impossible to guarantee such a situation. Down-votes are a simple and easily understandable way of expressing opinion with a statement.

Don't forget that each up-vote is 10 reputation so you only need to get one up-vote for *five* down-votes in order to break-even. You shouldn't be worried about losing reputation by participating; unless you're [Jeff denying the most up-voted feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949).

Comment: I think you're making the point, though: the current system doesn't encourage dissenting opinions, it encourages comments and downvotes--not the same thing at all. I'm not claiming I have a lock on the perfect solution; I'd actually love for *one of the answers* to provide an even better alternative. :)

Comment: @CodeGnome, I'm making the point that the current system has made a dissenting opinion a mouse-click away whereas you're suggesting that someone has to come up an answer. It's possible for there to be only one suggestion; that people either agree or disagree with. Or possible no answers might be needed. We could all have up-voted and down-voted your question _only_ and the final score would give an indication of the community's opinion.

Comment: @Ben: And that's the point: an "opinion" that's nothing more than a downvote is *worthless*. Opinions need to be backed up by argument and facts. If you can't, if all you can do is say, "I don't like it," then you're not having a discussion. You're having a shouting match. Whoever yells the loudest is the one left standing.

Comment: @NicolBolas And if someone has already written what I feel? Then the right thing to do is upvote the one who've echoed my sentiments, downvote those with whom I disagree and move on. Writing *another* text that just restates what my partisan's have already said would be silly.

Comment: @dmckee: If you're trying to evaluate the quality of an argument, how many people agree and/or disagree with it is irrelevant. What matters is the content of the argument itself. If you feel that your opinions and argument have been properly represented by someone else's post, what good does up/down-voting do?

Comment: @NicolBolas That is how you or I or Shog9 should evaluate the quality of an argument. How Meta.StackOverflow synthesizes the results of those many separate evaluations is by voting. And, yes, groups *can* be just as stupid and just as wrong as individuals, but it is what we've got.

Answer (score -5):

After listening to some feedback, I'd like to float the idea of having two separate tags:

1. [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), where no one gains or loses rep for *answers* so that we can facilitate discussion--which doesn't really fit into the Q&A format in the first place, if you think about it.
2. A new [polling](/questions/tagged/polling) tag, where we would link to the discussion, and ask people to vote. An up or down vote would be about consensus, not rep, and it would separate discussion from consensus in a trackable way.

Again, I'd like to point out that I don't think there's a perfect answer; I just think we should consider *all* the angles and try to find something *better* than what we have now. Democracy is hard work. :)

Comment: Yeah, that sounds good. Auto-CW discussion questions. Problem solved.

Comment: I don't see the use of this "polling tag" at all. That's exactly what voting on the discussion posts does.

Comment: @Ben I guess the idea would be that the votes in those tags would not have any effect on your rep etc., which sounds sensible to me, even though I don't think rep loss is an actual problem (see above)