# Remove 'Discussion' tag from Meta

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Given the following:

[How can Meta be made more conducive to discussions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124643/how-can-meta-be-made-more-conducive-to-discussions)

And the official closure response to many (most?) discussions:

"As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance."

Why is 'Discussion' one of the four tags presented as required for posting in Meta?

Comment: Irony alert: Your question is very much a discussion point, not a feature request...

Comment: Irony was on purpose. =)

Comment: Meta is not Q&A site.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus, love the profile image!

Comment: But neither is this a open-ended chat forum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't provide any examples of discussion questions you felt were wrongly closed (it is certainly false that "most" of them are closed).

However, I'm guessing that this is at least partly in response to your question "[If StackExchange acquired the Site That Shall Not Be Named](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170277/if-stackexchange-acquired-the-site-that-shall-not-be-named)" being closed as Not Constructive. That wasn't closed because it was a discussion, it was closed because it was about an impossible hypothetical (Stack Exchange acquiring Experts Exchange)- it's not *constructive* to discuss it because it could have no effect on the real world.

An example of a good discussion is here: ["Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users). It's not a feature request, a bug report, or a request for support. But it's discussing a real, *practical* issue- not an extremely far-fetched counterfactual.

Comment: You posit SE will never acquire another community site?

Comment: @Handprint: I certainly posit that SE will never acquire Experts Exchange, and am happy and comfortable in that position.

Comment: We *create* new ones all the time, in response to proposals on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), @Handprint - but past experience with *acquiring* sites has... not indicated that this works particularly well for anyone involved.

Comment: @Shog9, shame your comment is not an anwser to the closed Q D.R. mentions.

Comment: It doesn't answer that question, @Handprint.