# Proposal to (further) improve the quality of the voting system

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, voting, notifications

In the end the voting system has two main purposes:

- help future users find the questions/answers that are most likely to be helpful
- reward users that post good questions/answers

But editing is also a core part of the way Stack Overflow works. And it is not unsual for a good answer to be edited and transformed into a not so good or plain wrong answer. It is for example frequent that a poster will first answer a question with a short description, then edit it a few times to elaborate until the answer is complete.

It is therefore not uncommon that an originally correct answer becomes incorrect after those edits.

People who have upvoted the answer based on the original content would probably remove their upvote, leave a comment or even downvote if they were notified of the change and checked the final answer.

My question: **would it not improve the quality of the voting system if up/downvoters were able to monitor edits made to the posts they have voted on?**
It could for example be a page similar to the favorites page, giving users the choice to either use or ignore the information.

This would also help catching invalid edits made to old posts that receive less scrutiny than newer ones.

Comments:

- This is also applicable to questions.
- I found a [related popular-feature-request/unpopular-status-declined, for downvotes only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/179508). There might be others.
- One possible counter-argument would be about the noise it will generate - but I would not mind that noise: I already spend time reviewing suggested edits and I would be all the more interested in edits to posts that I have voted on in the past.
- We could even push it further and notify up/downvoters when new answers are posted that compete with answers that they have voted on - that would increase the likelihood that votes are fair and are the result of a well informed decision.

Comment: There are people who have voted on more then 10k questions and answers...you sure you want to notify them about changes?

Comment: I have about 100 favorites (generally on questions which receive higher than normal traffic) and get about 2 to 5 change notifications a day, mostly on recent favorites, and that includes **any changes to any posts in those threads**. So I guess on 10k votes one would not necessarily get more than 10 to 50 notifications a day which they can choose to ignore if they wish, especially if it is on a separate page (like favorites) and not a proper notification.

Comment: "It is therefore not uncommon that an originally correct answer becomes incorrect after those edits." - Do you have any examples you can point to of this actually happening? In my experience, it's far more likely that the opposite is the case, where an originally wrong answer becomes correct after an edit. Even more likely than that is that an answer which was once correct becomes incorrect over time as APIs change, which is a case not covered by these notifications.

Comment: @BradLarson [This is one example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1091068/829571) where an edit adds a false information, as pointed out by the last comment. Admittedly this edit was made a few minutes only after the original post but I think it illustrates the idea. Your last sentence makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @BradLarson Not really the same as the request, but i can see the benefit of notifying people who have answered questions when the question is editted. When the person edits the post some answers become wrong that may have been correct before. Same for retagging. Would also help people expand their answers when details are changed without OP's commenting on the answer saying it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume that you're right, and there is such a problem in the Stack Exchange network (which I don't believe or seen).

There are two options:

1. Those notifications will annoy too much.
2. Those notifications will be in a different page and be ignored.

I can't see how this feature can help the site, only how it can ruin it (specially that this problem just doesn't exist in my humble opinion)...

Comment: Following various comments I understand the point that using the notification system for that purpose could become annoying. Regarding your 2nd option, I think it could be applied to the suggested edits. Not everyone goes there, but I tend to use my daily vote limit on suggested edits regularly. Some people will ignore it, some won't. Finally, can you elaborate on "it can ruin it"?