# Motivation to edit when already downvoted

Tags: discussion, edits, down-votes, asking-questions, motivation

One thing I've noticed among new users is that their questions don't meet the basic quality guidelines, usually failing to include what they tried to solve their problem (on SO) or failing to include adequate details (SE in general). Naturally, these questions get downvoted due to their low quality.

If that person then edits their question into a genuinely good one (by following the guidelines given by others in comments), those downvotes still stand and I'm sure a number of people probably won't even look at the negative-score question if they see it on the question list.

This seems discouraging to me. Indeed, I've seen people just go and post the same question again (which, of course, gets closed as a duplicate), but that hardly solves anything.

I really don't know what to suggest be done about it. I just wanted to bring something up that's on my mind and open it to discussion on what we might do to encourage improving a bad question.

Comment: I think the problem here is that once I downvote a question or answer I won't have any notification if the post is updated. So the downvotes are never cancelled or reverted.

Comment: @n.1 Hmm... perhaps a notification could be emitted to say "this question, which you downvoted, has been edited, please review?"

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135626/should-you-be-notified-if-something-you-vote-on-is-edited-why-can-you-change-yo

Answer (score 7):

**There are already motivations to edit a question to make it better.** Editing can:

1. prevent any further downvotes, and maybe get upvotes from people who view the question after the edit,
2. prevent the question from being closed,
3. help the OP to avoid giving a (hopefully) wrong impression about themselves to more people that they already have.

**That the score of a question which has been greatly improved through editing still suffers from a bunch of initial downvotes that are not removed or reversed is not a bad thing.** This gives motivation to posters to give their best shot at producing a great question right off the bat rather than try to get away with getting the answer they need with minimum effort on their part. Besides, the people who had to read the initial terrible version of the question, vote, and (perhaps) comment to point out the problems won't get back the time they spent doing this.

Any changes made to the dynamics of voting **must not make it more onerous to downvote bad questions**. One example of something I can't support is having some sort of automatic notification sent to downvoters when a question is edited after their downvote. The OP here has suggested such a change in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231534/motivation-to-edit-when-already-downvoted#comment760993_231534) to the question:

> perhaps a notification could be emitted to say "this question, which you downvoted, has been edited, please review?"

There's already evidence that this would not work well. A great deal of the questions I come across in the reopen queue are back in the queue because they have trivial edits (for instance, punctuation changes), edits that do not actually address the issue for which the question was closed, or edits that do address the issue for which the question was closed but fail to address other problems. Having to deal with these in the reopen queue is bad enough. Downvoters should not get the equivalent of this in their inbox.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes sense.

Comment: Maybe one could limit the notifications to cases of substantial edits (more than typos) and only if the questioner requests it.