# Should I down vote a question if an edit is waiting for approval?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, down-votes

I see a question that I think should be down voted.
I see that it has an edit that is *waiting for approval* (gray edit button).

#### Question:

Should I

- down vote it because right now, as it is, it should be down voted? Or
- not vote at all, because it might be updated any moment?

My guess is the first one. What do you think?

Answer (score 9):

The ideal situation (if you can't *see* the suggested edit, of course) would be to downvote it now, follow it, and (after the notification you get from the edit) check back to see if the edit warrants retracting the downvote (or even an upvote). The edit might be rejected, after all.

Normally, you're not allowed to retract a downvote after five minutes, but an edit to the post allows you to reconsider your vote again.

Comment: It's not practical to check back all that I vote on

Comment: @alldani true, but most questions you consider voting on don't have a pending edit.

Comment: Also, note that the edit button can be grayed out for other reasons (e.g. if you have 5 pending suggested edits yourself). Hovering over the edit button will tell you the exact reason.

Comment: This calls for serious (long due) overhaul on the SE bookmarking system.

Comment: @alldani [something like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135626/should-you-be-notified-if-something-you-vote-on-is-edited-why-can-you-change-yo).

Comment: Yes! it should be a user choice, though.

Comment: What did you edit in the question btw? I picked up no change..

Comment: The title. You can click the [edited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/287757/revisions) link just below the question to inspect changes.

Comment: Ha! Forgive that miss. English is my fourth language.. :)

Comment: @alldani: You may want to try [my script to check back efficiently for edited posts you've voted on](http://stackapps.com/questions/6755/get-a-list-of-posts-youve-voted-on-that-have-been-edited).