# Upvoting and Downvoting notifications?

Tags: feature-request, voting, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: “I think I've fixed the issue now - please check”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c)

I have a small issue with down-voting and up-voting.

1. User X posts a question that doesn't have a point/question/code. I give him down-vote or vote to close his question. After 5 minutes he remakes his question and adds proper explanation/proper code - that question has a point of start.
2. User Y posts an answer to a question that is wrong, malformed, a lot of code issues. I give him down-vote. After 5 minutes he solves his errors and reedits his answer into a proper one.

Those 2 cases will still have my down-votes just because I didn't stay on that question.

Wouldn't be nice to be notified when some things like this happen? Maybe I want to up-vote question/answer.

Comment: I have the same issue but also with close votes: I would love the ability to rescind a close vote when the question has been sufficiently improved.

Comment: @Joe Close votes are slowly removed over time if there are no more votes to close so you really do not need to undo them. If the post has been improved then it will not be closed, but if the post is still bad, it will naturally get more close votes.

Comment: @JoshMein yeah, but in practice, people don't seem to be as excited about reopen-voting as they are about close-voting.

Comment: @PopularDemand He is referring to removing a close vote. You can vote to reopen even if you were one of the people who voted to close. Also, you could always flag the question for a moderator if you feel it should be reopened.

Comment: Well, you can always sift through [your downvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/147405/mihai-iorga?tab=votes&sort=downvote) (don't worry it's visible only to you) and quickly check what changed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd you got my ID wrong :). Still I won't check every day for changes in my down-votes.

Comment: @JoshMein yeah, I realize that, but there's a second set of cases where questions get closed before improvements are made.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That doesn't filter by edit since vote, so you'd have to click every freakin link to check for edits.

Comment: @Xaade true, but if checked frequently enough (e.g. daily) it should suffice. Mihai - sorry, started with the meta user then saw my error and just removed the meta from URL forgetting each site has different user ID. :-(