# Should a user reverse a downvote after I fix my post?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

On my answer at SO, I made a little mistake like writing `non-case-sensitive` instead of `case-sensitive`.  Someone commented that mistake and someone voted my answer down. I think it was the same person. I have fixed my answer, but the downvote remains.

Shouldn't that user reverse the downvote, because my answer is now correct?

**What is the best practice for this?**

Comment: Just because you *think* it was the same person doesn't mean you are right, or that your terminology was the only reason (or even any of the reasons) for the down-vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't know why he or she downvoted. It could be for that reason, or **any other**. It's likely the user doesn't know you fixed it. If someone left a comment, you can @-reply that commenter saying you fixed it. That **might** prompt them to look at your post and that **might** lead them to remove the downvote. But you don't even know (you **can't know**, you can only surmise or guess or believe) that the commenter is the downvoter. I quite often read an answer that I think is wrong but has a zero score, see a comment pointing out the error, and then downvote the post. And I usually don't come back later to see if the error was fixed. If that's what happened on your post, you should just accept the downvote as the cost of typing a little too quickly.

There was a feature request to [notify downvoters when posts were edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c); it was declined. You can vote for it if you think that might help.

Should is a loaded word. Ideally yes, if you use downvotes to say you think something is wrong, you should remove them once it's right. But the downvoter may not know you fixed it, or they may object to something else.

Answer (score 10):

The best practice here is to completely forget about this and move on.

The downvoter may or may not return to check your answer, and if they return they may or may not remove their downvote. It doesn't matter, other people will read your answer, and if it's correct, upvotes will soon appear.

Also, please don't assume that someone downvoted just because they also happened to post a comment. You can always reply to the comment and tell them you've fixed the mistake, but if the downvote doesn't go away, it might just be because they never downvoted in the first place.