# Getting down-votes reversed after updating answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, down-votes, bump

After improving an answer, it can be frustrating that the answer may never be reviewed again.  An updated answer can often sit at the bottom of a dead post and have no one with whom to direct a reply comment.

Is this negative reputation something one should just have to live with because the initial answer may have had minor errors even though the updated answer has none?

Would there be a benefit to something like an updated negative vote answer queue where your downvoted answer is something that could either be downvoted again if not made better or voted back to 0 if reviewer thinks the answer is worthy of not being "in the red"?

Comment: Editing bumps the question to the front page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is related, but not a duplicate since it's about questions, not answers and you also asked about starting a new review queue. [Is it bad etiquette to not remove a downvote on a question after the content of the question has been made better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215321/is-it-bad-etiquette-to-not-remove-a-downvote-on-a-question-after-the-content-of/215334#215334)

---

So for your question:

> Would there be a benefit to something like an updated negative vote
>   answer queue where your downvoted answer is something that could only
>   be reviewed once and either be downvoted again if not made better or
>   voted back to 0 if reviewer thinks the answer is worthy of not being
>   "in the red"?

As Robert Harvey mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215321/is-it-bad-etiquette-to-not-remove-a-downvote-on-a-question-after-the-content-of/215334#comment695210_215334)

> To put it another way, if the OP doesn't take the time to try and get
>   it right on the first attempt, they take their chances.

I think that sums it up pretty well. And that is what I think about poor answers that receive a downvote too.

So, no there should definitely not be a review queue for answers that were improved on. Just don't post poor answers in the first place.

Comment: I agree, but I think it might help motivate people more to improve their bad posts, which might result in less bad answers on the site.

Comment: True, but in a copy paste updated answer the reviewer could recognize that and down-vote it again.  But then it might be asking too much to have someone distinguish what's a copied answer and what's not.

Answer (score 6):

What I do when I down vote is leave a comment. I tell them how they can improve the post (ie site rules, what to try, etc), and add the edit link (type `[edit]`). I then tell them to ping me when they did so, and if they do, I tend to give an up vote.

This works well on my two main sites, but other sites may not work this way

Comment: Unfortunately, people often don't leave comments when down-voting.

Comment: I agree, but the system is not perfect