# percentage of down votes reversed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes, election, moderators

I have always had the, perhaps mistaken, impression that down votes are at least partially to alert the questioner that their question is poor quality so they have a chance to improve the question.

I thought of down votes as carrot and stick, albeit in reverse order: stick and carrot.

In my mind if a questioner improves a question that has been down-voted, and especially if they specifically address any comments explaining down votes, then the person who down voted the question should give consideration toward reversing the down vote.

However, my impression is that rarely happens.

It would be interesting to know the percentage of down votes reversed for each user, especially for moderator candidates.  I was wondering about this during the last moderator election, but did not think to formally ask each candidate what percentage of their down votes (or close votes) they reversed.

If the percentage of reversed down votes or reversed close votes for a moderator candidate was lower than average, indeed if it was not substantially higher than average, that would suggest to me the person would not make a good moderator.

The average voter might subscribe to the 'take-your-chances' stance described here:

[Getting down-votes reversed after updating answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225475/getting-down-votes-reversed-after-updating-answer)

but I do not think a good moderator would subscribe to that stance.

Would it be possible to include '% of down votes reversed' on user pages, at the very least for moderator candidates?

Comment: I don't think "% of down votes reversed" would be a particularly useful stat. For all you know, someone with a 0% of down votes reversed may have only down voted posts that were never actually improved.

Comment: @Yannis That is why I suggested relative to the user average.  A complex metric might be percentage of down votes reversed on edited questions.

Comment: I think there is no relationship between good moderation and reversed downvotes.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I happen to suspect otherwise and would appreciate having the information available when making my voting choices.

Comment: This would be meaningless for a couple of reasons: 1) Voting is confidential, whether up or down. 2) It would mean everyone is expected to monitor every single post they ever d/v in order to see if it was improved enough to warrant reversal, which is impossible given the number of horrendous questions that are posted and never improved. 3) It would skew the outlook of voters based on input that can't be fairly compared-I may d/v 100 really poor questions and have 10 improved enough to reverse, while you d/v 10 where 9 are substantially improved. 4) Irrelevant to moderation abilities.

Comment: @KenWhite I disagree.  Confidentiality could be maintained.  Votes up and down are already recorded on your users page and under your activity tab.  You could limit it to down votes within a 5-day period as is already done with close votes.  I have already mentioned it could be limited to posts that are down voted and then edited.  So, that subset could be further limited to posts that are down voted then edited within a 5-day period.  If % was reported then sample size (n) would be known.  Tallying the % would require doable programming and provide good information. Alerts already are sent.

Comment: @Mark: So for the five days before you throw your hat in the ring for a mod position, you carefully track -votes, vote heavily, and make sure to go back and review them for potential reversal. You now have a 95% reversal rate. What meaningful insight does that provide on your moderator skills? None. Suppose over that same 5 days, I do none of the above, vote normally, have many of the posts edited but not in a way that would cause me to undo my -vote, so I don't reverse most. (Or I see so many bad one because I spend more time here; I can't possible go back to review them all)? Value?

Comment: (continued): The point is that the measurement is about as meaningful as judging a coder's ability by LOC generated in a period of time. I know people who could wow you with the worthless LOC they generate in a single day. Rating them as impressive because of the amount of wasted keystrokes doesn't help the project get done (or when maintaining it later).

Comment: @KenWhite History of voting could be maintained to provide a trend line.  Further, it might be impossible for your reversal rate on edited posts to increased from 5% to 95% within 5 days unless sample size was very small.  My point is that good moderation means reviewing actions that negatively affect people's real-life ability to use this site.  My proposal provides an index to evaluate this.

Comment: @Mark: My point is that measuring voting reversals is meaningless info unless you're taking into account the overall number of questions seen, the quality of the posts before and after the edit, and in the end the measurement is *meaningless* with regard to moderator skills overall, just like total LOC in a five day period is a meaningless measurement of coding skills. I see no value at all in this statistic, and I say that as someone who quite often spends time every couple of days reviewing downvotes I've cast on **marginal** questions to see if I can do something to change the vote.

Comment: I'd also argue with your "negatively affect people's real life ability to use this site". A single vote cast by a single user doesn't negatively impact that ability; the single votes of *several* users can do so, perhaps. If a person asks so many questions that are heavily downvoted that they lose their ability to post here temporarily, perhaps they'll exert more effort to ask better questions in the future. IMO, the stat you're asking to collect and display is irrelevant and meaningless.

Comment: @KenWhite No index is perfect.  But I disagree that it is meaningless.  I have already mentioned that the posts under consideration could be limited to those down-voted, then edited within a 5-day period.  Also incorporating total number of posts seen, if that is desired, could perhaps be indexed somehow, perhaps by number of hours logged into the site, etc.  The index would be compared to average. The objective is not to provide a solo mechanism to judge mod skill.  Candidates would still be free to pitch themselves during an election cycle.

Comment: @KenWhite What I am suggesting is that someone who downvotes 10000 posts and never reverses any of them is at best over-extended for the job and at worst... ...lots of words come to mind...

Comment: @Mark: I understand what you're saying. I still feel it's an irrelevant statistic without taking a great many other factors into account, and that information won't really reflect anything outside of a relatively short window of time. I also am looking at it as someone with a considerable amount of experience at SO over a statistically significant period of time *and* who spends a reasonable period of time reviewing (and usually needing to take no action on) many downvotes I cast.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you, Ken.  I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, there is no relationship between good moderation and downvotes.

I will try to explain:

There are a lot of tags with bad, low quality questions. A downvote is often required on those questions. Those question get edited most of the times, either before or after they are closed.

That questions were edited after a downvote don't mean they got any better (there is a possibility, I agree).

Therefore I don't agree that this would be a good metric in any way, for any person, including moderators.

Comment: As I explained in the comments, I disagree.  I think people should have that information available when making their voting choices.  I can think of no reason people should not have access to that information.  The individual percentage would be relative to the average for all users.

Comment: We can also have a metric that says how late in the night they are on SO, but it not relevant. Just like this.

Comment: We disagree....

Comment: Heh, I guess you would have never voted for me on Programmers @MarkMiller... (7K downvotes, and proud of each and every one)

Comment: @MarkMiller The information should not be included because it's not in any way relevant.  That's a *great* reasons to not include it.  It is at best misleading, resulting in a moderator getting negative feedback for doing nothing wrong, or positive feedback for doing nothing good, or it's just not used and it is noise.  In neither case is it actually *helpful* nor does it improve the quality of elected moderators.  That's an *excellent* reason to not include it.

Comment: @Yannis It might depend on how many you reversed and what the overall average reversal percentage was.

Comment: @Servy Refusing to give credit to good questions simply because they required some initial improvement to reach that state seems like poor moderation.

Comment: @MarkMiller I'm pretty confident that you're going to see an average reversal rating of all votes on the site of something in the ballpark of 1-2%.  People just don't reverse votes very often.

Comment: @MarkMiller The thing is, I wouldn't expect a good moderator candidate to have reversed many of their downvotes. People who are interested in the janitorial aspects of SE tend to actively hunt down crap and downvote it to oblivion. And crap rarely gets improved.

Comment: @MarkMiller The vast majority of people are never going to read a question again after voting on it.  It's not that they re-read the post after the edit and made the intentional decision not to change their vote, rather they never re-evaluate the post in the first place.

Comment: @Servy That is my point.  A good moderator would reverse down votes when a question has been improved.

Comment: @Servy  To me that is poor moderation.

Comment: No. He doesn't. Votes are on the initial question and with a lot of luck, on the improved question.

Comment: @MarkMiller No, they wouldn't.  They'd be spending their time searching out more crap and dealing with it instead of wasting time reevaluating all of their past downvotes looking for the 1% that have actually been improved.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The luck factor should be substantially lower with a good moderator.

Comment: @MarkMiller It's highly inefficient use of one's time.  Very, very few posts ever get improved enough to be good questions when posted as poor questions.  Spending hours and hours looking through thousands of posts just to reverse a few dozen is wasted time.

Comment: No. It's based on the time that person has the question open in his browser, or the downvoter is active in commenting.

Comment: @MarkMiller I'm confident that if you looked at this stat, the people with a high reversal rate would be people who mis-click a lot and reverse their votes within a few seconds because of that, and not because they went back days later to check up on their posts.

Comment: @Servy Are you saying a moderator gives out so many down votes that they simply do not have the time to revisit them within 5 days?  A person giving out so many down votes that they cannot revisit them within 5 days would seem to be too busy to be a good moderator.

Comment: @Servy It seems I am getting so many down votes on this question simply for asking for information on which to make voting choices that I might be running the risk of getting banned.

Comment: @MarkMiller That's exactly what I'm saying.  You clearly don't actually downvote the crappy posts that you see.  There is no possible way that you've only read 7 crappy posts on this site, given the participation that you've made.  Even in the less crappy tags, there are still a lot of bad posts.  When you don't actually downvote the bad posts you see, it's easy to go back and evaluate them.  When you actually downvote the crap that you see, you don't have time to go back and check up on every single one.  Good moderators are also the people that *actively seek out the crap* to deal with it.

Comment: @MarkMiller It takes quite a bit to get question banned on meta, much more than on SO, but yes, it can happen.  If you repeatedly propose very unpopular suggestions you won't be able to continue to make such proposals.  It's an indication that you should be taking the time to consider your proposals more before posting them.

Comment: @Servy That is why I think percentage relative to user average is important.

Comment: @Servy I have considered this suggestion since before the last moderator election and I believe it is a rational one and a good one.

Comment: @MarkMiller Why, how is that relevant at all?  If anything the people with a really high reversal rate would be people who possibly wouldn't make good mods, because they almost certainly haven't downvoted enough posts to make re-evaluating them impractical.

Comment: @Mark: don't worry. A (bad) feature request of mine was swept away with a -11. Your -5 on it's own is no problem. Meta is a lot looser on the bad question threshold since feature requests tend to get a lot of downvotes / upvotes.

Comment: @Servy You have made on average 3.5 down-votes per day.  But you do not have the time to revisit them within 5 days?  Or the time to revisit within 5 days the subset that were edited?  I personally am a little skeptical.  However, I do not need to get banned.  So, I guess I can delete my good suggestion in a few days to protect my professional standing.

Comment: @MarkMiller The votes are skewed because deleted posts are not considered.  My actual count of downvotes is likely in the ballpark of double what it is listed as, maybe just 50% more.  Consider an evaluation time of 10 seconds.  I'm sure an average evaluation time would actually be quite a lot longer, but we'll be optimistic.  That would be 38 *hours* of evaluation time for me.  Imagine how much *productive* work I could do with that time doing things like downvoting/closing/deleting/editing bad posts, answering questions, etc.  All to reverse maybe a hundred downvotes at most.

Comment: @MarkMiller Oh, and you won't be able to delete this question because it has an answer with a positive score.

Comment: @Servy Thank you.  That is good.  It is a good suggestion and people should have access to the information I suggested.  The question should not be deleted.  People running for moderator can make their case at that point.  I do not understand why voters should not have that information and why candidates could not make their case during the election.

Comment: @Mark: Because (once again) **the information is irrelevant**. Having meaningless **irrelevant** information can falsely sway opinions. Everyone keeps pointing out the same flaw in your reasoning, and yet you keep insisting there is not flaw. When you post something, and *everyone who reads it says you're wrong*, it's highly likely you *are in fact wrong*. I've cast 15K+ votes on SO as of now, about 7K of which are downvotes. I only have 24 hours in a day and 7 days in a week, and there simply isn't enough time to review every d/v. There's too much garbage that needs to be removed every day.

Comment: @KenWhite It is your opinion that the information is irrelevant.  It is my opinion that the information is not irrelevant.  Why suppress information that some want to know?  I have not been convinced by anything anyone has posted here.  Everyone has not said I am wrong.  I have already said that candidates are free to pitch themselves and explain themselves during an election.

Comment: @Mark: No, it's the opinion of *everyone who has responded in an answer or comments to your suggestion*. The fact that *one user* wants to know it does not make it relevant. As others as well as I have said, **vote reversal averages** are not a meaningful statistic by any reasonable, knowledgeable standard. If you were more actively engaged in participating (by downvoting clearly poor quality questions when you see them), you would very quickly realize the lunacy of expecting anyone (especially serious mod candidates) to do so. It's clear you do not have that level of involvement.

Comment: (continued) as is clear by a quick check of your SO profile. As of now, member for 27 months; total votes cast: 1949. **Downvotes cast: 7**. Certainly, with an average of about 1 downvote every 4 months you have the ability to review them, but you **certainly** are not helping police the site by downvoting poor quality questions. Increase your own participation, **including exercising voting privileges for downvoting as well**, and then see if you feel the same way. Until you do so, I'll continue to assert my opinion that you're wrong.

Comment: @KenWhite I think I have one upvote, so I have that going for me, as Bill Murray might say.  We kind of seem to be repeating ourselves a little bit.  If everyone agrees with you then you have nothing to worry about.  Even if the proposed metric was adopted it would be ignored if everyone agrees with you.  So, I am the only one risking anything.

Comment: @Mark: No, if the proposed metric was added, it would be used **incorrectly** to influence people, and that is wrong. If I post information about someone that can be taken wholly out of context to appear negative and affect someone's opinion, that's wrong, and that's **exactly** what your proposed statistic would do. As I said, **increase your own participation** so that you have a voting record that can be judged **by the standard you're proposing for others**, and then make your suggestion. Until then...

Comment: @KenWhite The reason I do not down vote much is because they are over-used to punish first-time posters and to punish people who ask 'deep' questions.  Instead of punishing first-time posters I leave comments suggesting improvement and sometimes warning them that their post will soon be deleted if not improved.  Usually the post has garnered 3-6 down votes from others in short order.  What is the point of that?  Why should I add a 7th down-vote?  If the question is improved that rookie is still left with a question with 6 down votes and a very sour taste.  Close votes seem more defensible.

Comment: @Mark: No, they're not. You are supposed to **vote on the quality of the question**, not the experience of the person posting it. Votes reflect **quality, usefulness, and effort**, not **how new the poster is to the site**. Poor quality questions should be downvoted, regardless of whether the poster has 1 question or 10. It is the poster's responsibility to ask a clear question if they want answers. If you want to leave a comment suggesting improvement, feel free to do so, but either downvote it or follow up on your comment later to see if it's been accepted (and downvote then if it has not).

Comment: (continued). The worst possible solution is to just leave the poor quality question as is and hope it's later improved; that leads to the vast amount of noise and clutter that we all work very hard to avoid. The point of downvoting is to indicate the question is poor quality. Read the site guidelines for the *basic principles of how voting works at SE*; it's very clear what the purpose of voting serves. You're helping no one (including the poster) by leaving garbage that can obscure questions that deserve answers.

Comment: @KenWhite I disagree.  And so do many of the moderator candidates in the last election.  At least in my memory several of them openly pitched themselves on not 'bullying' new posters.  Those are the kinds of moderators I give most consideration to.

Comment: @Mark: OK. I give up. :-) As I said, I'll put more effort into considering your suggestion when you **increase your participation** so that you have some concept of the merit of that suggestion. We need moderators who have the ability to moderate, and being afraid (or too polite) to downvote poor quality questions IMO is a bad quality for someone being elected to help keep these sites aligned with their goals. The absolute **last thing** we need from a moderator is a wishy-washy "Oh, I can't do that! I might hurt someone's feelings!" attitude.

Comment: @KenWhite If I was wishy-washy I probably would not have posted this and I probably would have deleted it after the third down vote, while I still could.  So, I have that going for me.  I suppose I can try to bust more people's chops on their first post.

Comment: @Mark: I didn't say (or mean to imply) that to mean you personally. I specifically said "a moderator". It has nothing to do with "busting people's chops", either. It has everything to do with question quality. If a poster can't be bothered to put the effort into asking a question clearly, why should it stay here? The vast majority (I'd wager over 95%) of the poor quality questions are a) never edited despite comments, downvotes, or being put on hold, and b) posted by users who never come back after posting that question (or do so with a different account).