# Why do edited answers and questions seldom generate upvotes / un-downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Having a look at [these revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21695727/revisions), one can clearly see:

1. The Answer was plain wrong and it correctly induced downvotes.
2. The Answer got corrected and it should now be un-downvoted and possibly upvoted.

Why does this not happen?

Comment: Because people that downvoted have moved on and are not seeing your corrections. Eventually, *others* will see the answer and may upvote it again. Give it time, your post is only half a day old.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c

Comment: You might want to consider the site too - [sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) that get 8k questions/day are much less likely to get the same eyeballs on the vote as one that gets 30 questions/day.

Comment: People are lead by news globally. Old books are almost never taken from the shelves. It's always safe to write a new question of better quality. SE couldn't fully deal with "the news effect". The older the question the less chance that PEOPLE REMEMBER IT. Mb it would be good to delete the old negative question and to post the renewed old revised with an appropriate answer. Though those who have noticed "the old" could easily protest to "the new one" (i.e. better one) CONCLUSION: People seldom look on the old questions but the worst one that are negative..etc -will be noticed with attention 1st

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because the system requires human interaction.

How would the system know that the answer got corrected via the edit?  You could edit an answer 100 times and it could still be wrong.

Essentially, it's up to the community to recognize the edit and vote accordingly.

That said, you *could* draw attention to the edit by adding a comment like *"I've corrected my mistake, please re-evaluate your downvote,"* or something to that affect, towards any and/or all downvoters that have made themselves known in the comments previously.

That though, may come at a price as well, as **@AaronBertrand** mentioned in the comments:

> ...it will be very cluttered (each down-voter would need their own reply) and ... often the person who commented wasn't the one who down-voted, so you also may be pinging people who don't have a down-vote to change.

Comment: Of course that would require an individual `@reply` to every down-voter, assuming *any* left a comment.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Right, that's what I meant when I said _adding a comment ... towards any and/or all downvoters that made themselves known_.

Comment: I know that's what you said, but I wanted to emphasize that it will be very cluttered (each down-voter would need their own reply) and that it is unlikely to help in some cases, since most down-voters don't comment, and often the person who commented wasn't the one who down-voted, so you also may be pinging people who don't have a down-vote to change.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I hear you and agree. It is simply a stab at trying to draw attention to the fact that you've corrected your mistake and a plea towards those who have downvoted to re-evaluate that vote.  As stated, it's essentially up to the community to recognize the edit and vote accordingly.  What else can you do?

Answer (score 3):

For the most part content is a forward moving process. Users poll for content, new content comes in, content is evaluated, users go back to polling for new content.

There isn't really a go back and re-evaluate step because there is such a large amount of new content. As linked in a comment, there was a feature request to notify down voters of edits, but it has not gained much traction.

Aside from users who are only evaluating new content, there are also users who try to solve their problem by looking at content. If the edited content is evaluated by them and is correct, they will potentially upvote it.

In the long run, if the edited content is a legitimate solution it will generate upvotes. Overall though, and in order to avoid downvotes, it is important to just be correct the first time instead of trying to be [the fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/178816).

Comment: This only applies to Stack Overflow and maybe a few other sites with lots of activity, though.

Comment: @3ventic - The question did link to a Stack Overflow post :) But you are correct in that this applies to exchanges with high activity. Exchanges with low activity to not have even a fraction of the issues Stack Overflow has from just normal wear and tear. Soon Stack Overflow will have its own meta and these types of questions will not seem to imply a network wide context.

Comment: That is true, but mine was just a note. Besides, there's the [meta-tag:stackoverflow] tag for SO specific questions.