# Keep track of your rejected edits

Tags: support, edits, rejected-edits

It seems you don't get informed in the upper Inbox message in case one of your edits got rejected. If an edit got accepted you see the +2 Rep in the recent Reputations, but you never know if something was wrong with one of your edits if you don't keep track of them yourself.

Since you don't get an information message in this case (see [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor?rq=1)) How is it possible to track them yourself?

Comment: On the history page? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history

Comment: No, that is only if you used the Review functionality. I woud like to know about all edits.

Comment: I fear no such way exists. You can leave [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1069083/rubo77?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) always open in a tab and have a userscript that will auto refresh, detect new activity, "crawl" the new activity and if rejected alert in some way.

Comment: So I started a feature-request: [show-the-outcome-of-suggested-edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230989/)

Comment: This information is available in the [user api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-suggested-edits#order=desc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) add this to the run `/2.2/me/suggested-edits?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow` which gives you a JSON output. If the object contains a `rejection_date` you have something to look after...

Comment: Profile > activity > suggestions is not it?

Comment: No, that doesen't show the outcome, that's why I started that feature request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). I created [this simple query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/190256/suggested-edit-rejections-for-user?UserId=1069083) that will show you your rejected suggested edits. The question title with just an ID displayed have been deleted.

Using the API will give you access to real time data. Currently the data explorer refreshes it's data once a week.

Comment: Great! that works. And I added the link to the rejected text here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/190297/suggested-edit-rejections-for-user

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more. I should enter a captcha at the bottom, but there is none to read (firefox 32)

Comment: @rubo77 The query in my answer and your comment are still working for me in Chrome 37. Maybe try a different browser? If problems continue, you may want ask a new question.

Comment: I did: [Data Explorer captha doesn't work with google blocked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240086) And I found out while questioning it: you have to enabel google to see the Captcha

Comment: I enhanced the query a bit: sorted by creation date descending: http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/228012/suggested-edit-rejections-for-user?UserId=34298

Answer (score 6):

You can get your rejected edits from the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com)

The topic User has an entry for [Me Suggested Edits](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-suggested-edits)

Make sure you hit the button `Get Token` first before you hit `Run`.

<sub>[and don't use IE because it won't give you a token...](https://stackapps.com/questions/4581/get-token-button-in-try-it-doesnt-give-me-a-key-in-ie11)</sub>

[image]

The result will look like this:

```
"items": [
    {
      "proposing_user": {
        "reputation": 13205,
        "user_id": 578411,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj33e.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "rene",
        "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene"
      },
      "approval_date": 1298996673,
      "creation_date": 1298996632,
      "post_type": "question",
      "post_id": 5157197,
      "suggested_edit_id": 11561,
      "comment": "layoutr of code "
    },
    {
      "proposing_user": {
        "reputation": 13205,
        "user_id": 578411,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj33e.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "rene",
        "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene"
      },
      "approval_date": 1298985879,
      "creation_date": 1298985799,
      "post_type": "question",
      "post_id": 5155003,
      "suggested_edit_id": 11482,
      "comment": "layoiut of the unions"
    },
    {
      "proposing_user": {
        "reputation": 13205,
        "user_id": 578411,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj33e.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "rene",
        "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene"
      },
      "rejection_date": 1298981760,
      "creation_date": 1298980107,
      "post_type": "question",
      "post_id": 5154076,
      "suggested_edit_id": 11442,
      "comment": "formatting  of folders"
    },
```

If you flatten the json you can get the links to your rejected edits like so:

```
var p = JSON.parse('{"items": [  { "proposing_user": {"reputation": 13205,"user_id": 578411,...... ');   // add all JSON here as one line...

var br, a, i, item, d = document.getElementById('r');
for(i in p.items)
{
    item = p.items[i];
    if (item.rejection_date)
    {
        br = document.createElement('br');
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.innerHTML = item.suggested_edit_id.toString();
        a.setAttribute('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/'+item.suggested_edit_id.toString());
        d.appendChild(a);
        d.appendChild(br); 
    }
}
```

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2eJu/) with my rejected edits...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you've looked into @3ventic's suggestion far enough. If you click on [a suggested edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4629413) in [your history of suggestion activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069083/rubo77?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) (borrowed the link to your SO profile from @ShadowWizard), you'll see which reviewers took what actions on your suggestion. You can check each one manually this way, or you can click `(more)` under the list of reviewer actions (if any) to see your editor stats at the bottom. From this I see that, on SO at the time of this post:

> **·**   [rubo77](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069083/rubo77) had 24 edit suggestions approved, and 18 edit suggestions rejected

Comment: Who said my name? ;)

Comment: That worked better than I expected! I thought I had to say it three times while facing a mirror... :D

Comment: I can see how many, but I cannot see which and which were rejected this way (without clicking on each single one), can I?

Comment: If you click each `suggested edit` link individually, you can. It's not as nice as having the decisions for each summarized on the suggestion activity page would be, but it's a decent workaround for a small number of edits.