# Data Explorer CAPTCHA doesn't work with Google blocked

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer, google, captcha

I tried to do this again:

> [Keep track of your rejected edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230987/keep-track-of-your-rejected-edits)

but when I [follow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/190297/suggested-edit-rejections-for-user) the link in the accepted answer, I get no CAPTCHA when I click on "I am a Human Being".

> [image: screenshot with error]

I use Firefox 32 with NoScript and have blocked `google.com`.

When I enable Google temporarily in NoScript, it works.

Please allow the use of Stack Exchange with Google blocked.

Comment: ... [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#whyrecaptcha)'s are served by Google, so what did you expect? If you block Google, it's going to break.

Comment: Then There must be an alternative fallback method, or at least a hint, that you need to enable google for this. It took me ages to find out the problem

Answer (score 6):

I cannot reproduce this issue on a standard PC (not blocking Google). We rely on Google to provide reCAPTCHA and also as a login provider for our sites. If you block Google, reCAPTCHA and login via Google will not work. It thus is a requirement of our websites, to some degree, that Google is not blocked. This is by design.

Comment: I will look into adding an error message for this case though, as not showing anything and still letting you click the submit button is fairly confusing.