# Subscribe downvoters to posts they downvoted

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, down-votes

It's really frustrating when you post a new question, and a person down votes it and then they close the tab. The OP can add a comment such as "Why down vote?", the post would still be down voted even though the OP fixed the issue making the down vote invalid. Then it would still be -1, unless someone up votes the post (but then this gets tricky: the up voter just wanted to fix the -1, not necessarily up vote it and give rep). So a solution: subscribe the down voter to the question, no?

That'd mean he would get notifications when OP's post is edited or new comments on the question or comment.

Comment: I have never heard of or seen an incident in which someone up votes a post just to get it back up to 0.

Comment: @Vinz243 Because [voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Downvotes simply signify disagreement.

Comment: @Doorknob I think he means generally across the whole network.

Comment: This is also discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c?rq=1).

Comment: @Benjamin happened to me. Or this is my interpretation. Got -1 then 0 and +5 rep

Comment: Benjamin - yep, it happens a fair bit, and usually people comment that they added the +1 to offset a -1 they felt was undeserved :-)

Comment: @Vinz243 Would you please link to the question?

Comment: @RoryAlsop In that case they are also just saying that it is a good question.

Comment: @Benjamin There's a difference between saying "this is a good question" and "this is a question that does not deserve to stand at -1."

Comment: @Louis Okay, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid this would have the opposite effect. If you auto-subscribe a downvoter to something, you're just going to annoy them and make people less likely to downvote. There's already *not enough* downvoting. I think all this solution would do is lead to more broken windows being left around.

What about sites that have been around for a long time? In some places I have thousands of downvotes. Many of those posts are long-since deleted, but many are not. Do I really need to be notified of a three-year-old post that has had some minor issue fixed but the underlying issue that attracted my downvote has not been addressed?

Further, auto-subscribing someone to content via some other unrelated action smells rather like a certain canned luncheon meat.

Comment: That is what I am saying.