# Future review: Revisit answers later

Tags: feature-request

Perhaps others are better about this, but I, personally, have not been very consistent about upvoting good answers.  This is not for lack of desire; rather in the heat of the moment (servers down, etc.), I'm not thinking about formally recognizing good answers, I'm simply looking for a solution as quickly as I can.

On the flip side, when I'm just browsing, I'm rarely trying to solve an issue, so I lack the immediate "I just tested this method and it worked for me" experiential basis upon which to upvote (or downvote) anything.  Also, it's rather difficult to remember many of the questions/answers that I visited previously in the heat of the moment.

It would be really nice if I could "flag" answers for future review.  The flagged answer would be put into a queue for me to visit later and decide whether to upvote or downvote.

I ***want*** to recognize good answers, but I also want to test the answer for myself before I upvote it.  This would provide an easy way to revisit answers later after validation.

Comment: Many people use the "favorites" feature for this. Will that not suffice?

Comment: Hmm, hadn't considered that, but that might work.  I was actually imagining a system that was a little more pro-active about reminding me to review things that I had flagged.  Basically, if I flag it, next time I log in, remind me to go back and look at the question while things are hopefully still fresh in my mind.

Comment: The downside of "favoriting" something would be that I would have to "unfavorite" it after I reviewed it, unless I truly wanted to keep it as a favorite.

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285470/opt-in-notifications-to-revisit-a-downvoted-post

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you may be overthinking on voting if you need to often come back later in order to do so.

The guidelines on up and down voting are not whether posts are perfect or terrible. It is simply whether they appear to be useful or not.

If I want to revisit a question later I favorite it, and usually vote at the same time.