# Making Stack Exchange a more inviting place for new users

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, new-users, se-quality-project

Stack Exchange is a wonderful and invaluable community... once you're part of it. New users who aren't familiar with how SE works may have a different impression of our community though. For instance, I know a couple programmers with 10+ years of experience that are too scared to post on SE because of how the community responded to their first questions. There are also a number of blog posts / forum topics discussing how pedantic the community can *appear* to be ([here is a well-mannered example](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php) for instance).

As mentioned in that blog post, Stack Exchange has two main purposes: short-term help with questions and long-term repositories of good questions and answers that can help people in the future with similar questions. Low-quality questions are a serious issue for the latter of the two, and can be aggravating to deal with i.e. "I've closed countless questions today -- why can't users do something as simple as read question asking guidelines before posting?!" In consequence, low-quality questions are forcefully evicted from the site.

If we're looking to improve new user experience, this is a place we can work on. The below items may seem trivial, but UX can have substantially more impact than it appears to have at face value.

## Negative feedback lingers even after questions are revised

I asked [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344021/wishful-thinking-to-the-point-of-lunacy) a while back and it ended up coming off slightly rant-y despite my intentions. Someone commented that this was a potential issue, and the question ended up being downvoted at least once. I agreed with the comment, revised my question, yet to this day I still have a downvote on it. It doesn't make much of a difference when weighted with the upvotes and the activity on the question, but this may not always be the case.

Imagine I post a question that isn't particularly noteworthy but my wording is off. I get a couple downvotes, I revise, but the negative feedback still lingers. As a new user, I would feel shunned. When it comes to downvotes, even though I tried to improve myself and my question, the community spit on me and didn't look back.

## Downvotes aren't always accompanied with explanation

In the question I linked in the previous section, it may have been the case that the downvote lingering isn't actually because of my initial wording of the question. Maybe it's something completely different. I have no clue why it was downvoted though, and as a result, have no idea what I can improve. Will my question forever have an issue because I don't know what's wrong with it? A specific and arbitrary example is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779178/what-is-the-equivalent-of-string-in-c). It has downvotes, but no one bothered to explain why. How is the asker supposed to know what's wrong with it?

## Closing topics gives off the wrong impression

As a new user, say I post a low-quality question and it gets closed. For discussion's sake, let's say it was too broad. This gives me the impression that my *question* was bad and that it shouldn't be on SE. The true issue was that my presentation was wrong and that my question is still valuable. Even as someone who's used SE for a couple years and understands that closing, revision, and re-opening of questions is standard procedure and nothing personal, I can't help but feel bad inside and slightly ostracized from the community. Using the wording "on hold" instead of "closed" for the first five days doesn't make me feel less bad either.

## Solutions

I've been a member of SE for two years, but I'm not an avid user of SE. I'm not so presumptuous to claim that particular ideas are the best solutions for these problems. The following are ideas that are meant to be taken into consideration when developing solutions to the above issues rather than solutions meant to be implemented as-is.

#### Negative lingering feedback

I think moving question feedback to behind the scenes would be a good idea. As a non-participant viewer of the question, whether I found it from a Google search or I'm just browsing SE, I want to see a discussion that is relevant — not idiosyncrasies of SE like "please use the right tag". As someone answering a question, I'm also not concerned with those same things.

Moderation-related topics like tag usage, duplicate suggestions, etc are only relevant to users interested in moderation, and as such comments aren't really the most appropriate place for these kinds of topics. In the perfect SE, I see discussion of moderation in a separate environment from Q&A. A similar feature can be found in wikis in the form of talk pages where the contents of the page are discussed. This will ensure that moderation doesn't interfere with Q&A, new viewer bias due to comments pointing out issues is no longer an issue, and the question isn't branded as "that bad question".

#### Downvotes without explanation

This could potentially be resolved by augmenting downvotes with flags. Flagging would have to be expanded to support this though. See a question that's too broad? You could downvote it, but optimally you'd flag it as too broad, the question is automatically downvoted, and the poster is notified specifically how their question can be improved. This could also help with the previous point — if a question was flagged+downvoted 5 times due to being too broad and put on-hold, if and when the question is revised and re-opened, poof all of the no longer relevant downvotes are removed.

#### Closing topics gives off the wrong impression

As an asker, it would be more friendly to be told "Your question is awaiting revision" than "Your question has been put on-hold/closed".

---

Again, some of these may seem like trivial issues, but new user experience isn't improved by rules and regulations — it's improved by making SE a friendly place to participate in for new users who may not yet understand how SE works.

Comment: Although there are no comments explaining the down votes on the example you linked to, there is a useful hint in one of the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35779221/578411

Comment: Why do you think a downvote should be done through flagging? Downvote on a question means it is neither well-researched nor clear/useful. Sometimes, it has nothing to do with the question being too broad or primarily opinion-based. Some users could cancel or reverse their downvotes if they find it edited, but there are others who don't. You can just move on. A lesson learned.

Comment: @rene Can you elaborate a bit on that for me? I'm not seeing what's being hinted. At face value it looks like he's just answering the question.

Comment: @Drew last line: *You should seriously note to do some better research before asking at Stack Overflow, or ask your question more clearly. std::string is ubiquitous.*

Comment: @rene Oh, my screen centered on the wrong answer so I was looking at the wrong one -- sorry! I'll find a better example to substitute into the OP.

Comment: @rene Good suggestion on clarification for who needs to do revision -- I'll add that to the OP. As for mandatory comments, that's not what I'm suggesting. Mandatory comments are problematic because 1) they make it harder to vote and 2) users may just type random characters to fulfill that requirement, making the feature useless. This is likely why that feature request was declined. What I'm suggesting is entirely different and not subject to either of those weaknesses though. It is not noticeably more difficult to downvote and random reasons are a non-issue.

Comment: @Rathony See "Flagging would have to be expanded to support this though." Flags are not encompassing enough to support this behavior in their current state. As for cancelling flags, flags could be extended to support that as well, but I'm not sure why you'd need to cancel a flag unless the question was edited, in which case we should probably have reviewing of flags when posts are edited to be part of the moderation process.

Comment: @DrewI was referring to a downvote, not flagging.

Comment: @Rathony The main benefit of using flags as a front for downvotes is that the poster is told what's wrong with their post. The added benefit is that those downvotes can go away when the issue is resolved (e.g. too broad downvotes/flags when the question is re-opened)

Comment: @Drew The main disadvantage of using flags as a front for downvotes is there are many other cases where a downvote is much preferred than flagging. Downvote and flag have different functions and only flagging for "spam" or "offensive (rude)" accompanies automatic downvote. Others, too broad, primarily opinion-based, etc don't accompany automatic downvotes because some people don't feel like downvoting it when they flag it. It's users' option.

Comment: @Rathony As per the discussion I had with Cai and his answer, I've revised the OP to suggest flags as an augment rather than a replacement to downvotes. As for not wanting an automatic downvote, I'm not sure how beneficial that is. The question's rating should reflect how well-communicated it is. The only merit of not downvoting for that reason is that you anticipate the poster will correct the issue, which is a non-issue with automatic flag downvotes since they're automatically removed as well.

Comment: @Drew Your question and edit prove that flags and downvotes should be separated. I downvoted your question because I don't agree with you and didn't flag it because I don't think your question is off-topic. You see? There is no reason to flag your question here. Also, please note voting on Meta is generally for agreement or disagreement.

Comment: Most, if not all, of the suggestions were already suggested at some point, in different variations. All in all, being "inviting to new users" will most likely also mean "much worse quality". Personally, I prefer to keep the quality, even if it will hurt the feelings of new users.

Comment: @ShadowWizard None of my suggestions decrease the quality of questions on SE

Comment: @Rathony Good point. As per the edit you mention though, my suggestion is augmentation instead of replacement, so you'd still be able to downvote it without flagging.

Comment: @Drew not being able to downvote without flagging means fatal blow to quality. Sometimes a question is on topic, but deserves a downvote. Without being able to downvote properly, those questions will flourish, and flood Stack Overflow. (Keep in mind that question rate limiting is based on downvotes)

Comment: @Drew Now you seem to understand my point. Thanks. Sometimes, just moving on is the best policy and will give you less stress. Also, don't worry about downvotes too much. What do you have to lose? Stack Exchange is a very weird place and you will know what I mean as time goes by.

Comment: @Rathony I have no problem with downvotes. New users on the other hand do. They are likely not concerned with future reputation yet, and their only concern is getting their question answered -- downvotes matter a lot more in this respect as it's a bad first impression and it means their question is unlikely to gain attention (for instance I mostly ignore questions with negative scores).

Comment: @ShadowWizard See revised proposal. Downvoting requiring flagging is no longer suggested.

Comment: @Drew New users who don't like the way SE works can go to other places where there are no downvotes. There are many places. Why come to SE? My advice to you is don't care so much about them nor do you need to fight for them. They come and go even if we don't downvote.

Comment: @Rathony SE is currently looking at ways to improve new user experience. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be so much related with the linked question. SE doesn't need users who don't like downvotes and don't want to learn and follow the way SE works as much as they don't need SE.

Comment: I mostly disagree with your ideas, but this is very well put together, especially considering that it goes over once again that tired old idea of downvote explanations.

Comment: @Drew OK, now it is not fatal blow.

Comment: Why this question, with positive criticism, and truth inside, is so much downvoted. The community prefer to make its eyes bleed instead of discussing to solve problems?

Answer (score 5):

I do agree on your question title, but not to all features you propose.

> I think moving question feedback to behind the scenes would be a good idea

That would be a good idea when comments turn out in discussions (we have chat for that), but otherwise it doesn't. Relevant comments don't only help the user who asks the question (to take action), but it also help others passing by to see if there are problems with the question and possibly with the answers it will receive.

As an example, this X/Y problem comment: *Are you sure you need to do X? Please explain why you need this. It seems you are trying to solve this the wrong way around.* That comment is useful to get the asker clarify their question, but also for someone else reading to diagnose their own problem.

> Moderation-related topics like tag usage, duplicate suggestions, etc are only relevant to users interested in moderation

Certainly not. I often find useful related or duplicate posts in comments. Not all posts are closed as duplicate eventually, but they are still very useful!

> Downvotes without explanation

Downvotes are a mechanism of moderation. Something that needs a downvote doesn't always need a flag / close vote. A question can be clear, not too broad, and not off-topic, but still not well-researched, etc. Forcing users to explain their downvotes is a no-go. It has been requested multiple times. Votes are anonymous, no matter is they are up or down.

> Closing topics gives off the wrong impression

The close message is often seen as harsh, while I have never experienced it myself that way. (I haven't had any of my posts closed as anything else than duplicate, so maybe I am the wrong person to say this) If there is a better message that still has the same clear message to the user, I am totally okay with that.

Comment: Revised the forced downvoting explanation into flags being an augment for that. As for #2, what's stopping you from viewing the moderation page if you're interested in moderation? It would be visible to everyone. The only reason for separating Q&A and moderation is that moderation isn't Q&A and isn't relevant to non-SE members finding topics through Google.

Comment: @Drew the possible duplicate comment specifically is useful beyond moderation.  Take the intent of duplicates to begin with.  It points users to a question with an answer that may address my problem.  Unfortunately, not every duplicate question gets 5 votes (and they eventually age away), so an older question might not have any duplicate votes, but the comment will point me towards a potential duplicate where I might find an answer to my question even if the link in the banner isn't there.

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with the sentiment. I really do, a lot. But I disagree with the causes and your proposed solutions. Let me explain why.

> #### Negative feedback lingers even after questions are revised

Voting is there for a reason. If you improve your post and you continue to post improved content then it's inconsequential in terms of reputation and overall post scores. If you keep getting downvotes then you are doing something wrong. The first downvotes you get are always going to be unpleasant but there is no way around it, voting is an integral part of the system.

> I think moving question feedback to behind the scenes would be a good idea. As a non-participant viewer of the question, whether I found it from a Google search or I'm just browsing SE, I want to see a discussion that is relevant -- not idiosyncrasies of SE like "please use the right tag"

This is a bad idea. New users not knowing these idiosyncrasies is exactly what causes the problem in the first place. People think this is like any old forum and post as such. Well, it isn't and they shouldn't—The way to tackle that and improve the experience for everyone involved is to let users know what Stack Exchange is and what is expected, up front and as soon as possible—not after they have posted a question.

> This will ensure that moderation doesn't interfere with Q&A, new viewer bias due to obsolete comments pointing out issues is no longer an issue

Comments are meant to be temporary and obsolete comments should be deleted. There is a flag reason exactly for this.

---

> #### Downvotes aren't always accompanied with explanation

This is a long running topic and there have been feature-requests asking for mandatory explinations of downvotes. It's not going to happen. You can't force people to explain their voting. I personally like being able to vote on posts without having to explain myself and my voting would decrease a hell of a lot if I did have to. I also enjoy being able to comment without people automatically linking that to a downvote that I may or may not have cast.

See [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) and the countless linked questions.

> Flag it as too broad, the question is automatically downvoted, and the poster is notified specifically how their question can be improved. ... if and when the question is revised and re-opened, poof all of the no longer relevant downvotes are removed.

This isn't actually a bad idea. But, it shouldn't be a replacement for regular voting but *in addition* to it. You don't know why people are downvoting, so give them the choice. If they're downvoting because it is too broad, stick with the auto-downvote. Otherwise, vote as normal.

---

> #### Closing topics gives off the wrong impression

> This gives me the impression that my question was bad and that it shouldn't be on SE.

That *is* the case. If the question is off-topic / too broad etc. then it shouldn't be on Stack Exchange.

> As an asker, it would be more friendly to be told "Your question is awaiting revision" than "Your question has been put on-hold/closed".

That's essentially what happens. The [on-hold] notice already says this:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

It can seem harsh and discouraging for new users when their questions are closed and maybe a better tone could be helpful in the notice wordings but closing questions is important.

The real solution is to help and encourage users to post better content to begin with.

Comment: "If you keep participating in SE small amounts of downvotes don't matter" If you're concerned about reputation, then that's correct. New users aren't concerned about reputation though -- their concerns are much more short-term. "New users should know idiosyncrasies" OPs would be able to see moderation topics open on their question. "There is a flag for obsolete comments" Ah, apologies! I never noticed that. I'll remove that from the OP.

Comment: "You can't force people to explain their voting" You're right. Even with my suggestion, you may still have people who just leave the first option selected and vote, even if that's not the right reason. Augmentation sounds like a better idea. "I like being able to vote without explaining myself" The difference in difficulty between downvoting and flagging a post is small -- would it really change how much you downvote?

Comment: "If it's too board etc, then it shouldn't be on SE" Yes. In its current state, it does not belong on SE. It has the potential to belong on SE if it's revised and presented better though. We communicate that the problem the asker is experiencing shouldn't be on SE, when this really isn't the case except for off-topic -- the issue is with how they word it. "on-hold can seem harsh; maybe a better tone would help" That's pretty much what I'm suggesting. A less-harsh wording that encourages the asker to continue participating.

Comment: I understand new users feelings on downvotes aren't really about reputation but I don't see a solution to that, voting is an important indicator of post quality and that is important information for everyone so you can't move that behind the scenes.

Comment: As for the flag-auto-downvote I said that would be a good idea in addition to normal voting yes, but anything that replaces normal voting or enforces explaining votes would drastically change voting habits, yes.

Comment: To echo @drew a bit "inconsequential in terms of reputation and overall post scores." is not the issue, quality questions and answers are. After being down-voted, a user may edit their question to a be a really excellent, useful one, but it will still maintain a downvote and be seen as bad. The downvote is useful at first, but probably loses any value after edits.

The real feature request we need is that downvoters should be notified when a question is edited in order to take advantage of the oppurtunity to undo their vote (as it stands , that oppurtunity is almost always wasted).

Comment: Along those lines, I've voted here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c