# Can we get a ping when a downvoted Q/A was subsequently edited?

Tags: feature-request, edits, down-votes, notifications

I'm one of these people who tends to leave a comment when I downvote and every now and then, the OP edits their post and pings me back they did and then I remove my downvote most of the time and even upvote every once in a blue moon...  **:-)**

However, I noticed that one of my comments on one of my downvotes was upvoted 3 times and the answer was downvoted for the same amount of times *but now it's actually a good answer.* (and I have no way of contacting the additional 3 downvoters)

Can we have an additional *option¹* to be pinged whenever an edit was made on one of our downvotes for the few times that I don't leave a comment?

Note¹: Optional because there might be people who don't want any extra pings because they get too many already.
Note²: It would be more welcoming to new users who generally don't know how the SE network works and get downvotes because of semantics and not because of their actual question or answer...
**Note³: [This one is similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c) and highly upvoted, but that one is asking to make it mandatory, whereas this is broader *and optional*.**

Comment: @random: Thanks.  I've upvoted them all...  **;-)**