# Why can new users only answer every 30 minutes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, new-users

Since a new user to Stack Overflow like me can only post an answer to a question every 30 minutes, this makes it extremely irrelevant for new users and will in short; drive users away from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) - in particular, this [answer](/a/164900) states "Users with < 125 rep must [wait 3 minutes between answers on most Stack Exchange sites](/q/23038), but [must wait 30 minutes between answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering-limit). The longer wait time between answers on Stack Overflow was implemented as part of the [response to a flood of ChatGPT answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421991)."

Comment: Why do you *want* to post answers so quickly? How does being unable to do so make the site "irrelevant"? Can you elaborate a bit? I notice that [the only "answer" you've posted on Stack Overflow thus far](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75121397/3122701) isn't actually an answer at all.

Comment: _will in short; drive users away from Stack Overflow_ ... over 5000 new questions were posted on SO yesterday

Comment: Indeed, 30 minutes is far too quick. One question per twelve hours seems far more reasonable, if you have another question ready to post within 30 minutes of the previous one, you aren't making nearly enough effort at all.

Comment: I'd struggle to find, evaluate & answer two questions an hour anyway, so what's the rush? [I've managed three in three hours today, & that's probably more than my average day.]

Comment: NewUsers!=NewAccounts.

Answer (score 11):

It helps to limit spammers who would like nothing less than to post spam much more quickly than every 30 minutes. It is easier to clean up one spam post than 10.

Also some people just don't quite get the site when they start out. They answer off-topic questions or don't answer properly at all or ask questions in the answer space or add me too as an answer. We'd like to be able to catch and warn such people before they become answer banned entirely.

Anyway, the Stack Overflow limit would seem to be back to 3 minutes now that the worst of the ChatGPT wave is over. Proof [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937572/phpredis-and-locking/74937701#74937701) and [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937663/awk-invalid-char-in-expression/74937722#74937722) were posted approximately 3 minutes apart on 28th December by a user that almost certainly never made it to 125 rep.

Comment: Considering that the 2 answers were posted < 3 minutes apart, this answer is actually also invalided by the answers it uses to validate itself that the change has been reverted. If those answers *are* proof, they are proof that the 3 minute rate limit is also not in affect. More likely the answers were posted by an account that was merged. You shouldn't use a singular example, without citation (such as from a staff member), as evidence.

Comment: What I find worse is it appear you used this one example to edit the aforementioned FAQ... If the 3 minute rule was reinstated, I would expect a staff member to state so, or they would be the one to amend the FAQ article.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422672/has-the-30-minute-rate-limit-between-successive-answers-from-125-reputation-use

Comment: I've seen others. I saw no reason to make a long list.