# Tracking a post

Tags: feature-request, tracking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark questions to receive notifications and updates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates)

In stackoverflow and related sites, you get alerts only if you have got something to do with the post i.e. you asked the Q, you answered and got upvotes or comments, you commented and someone added another comment.

However, there are times when a question might seem interesting but you are not able to contribute to the question in any way (due to lack of knowledge or whatever). You would still like to keep track of all the new activity in the post. So we should have some mechanism where you can mark a post for tracking and get alerts whenever there are new answers, comments or acceptance of an answer.

Comment: this has been suggested before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates