# Can I get notified of changes to a selected question?

Tags: support, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)
>   [Mark questions to receive notifications and updates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/218334)

Suppose someone asks an interesting question, and I want to get notified about answers or comments it receives, even though I am just a "viewer" of this question, and not a "contributor."

How can I do it?

Alternatively, can I make a "bookmarks list" of questions as part of my user profile?

Comment: Check this out http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225516/220601 You may like it. An elegant Solution of how you can get notifications on a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For answers notification, you could subscribe question into your favorite feed reader.

> eg., https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/51254

When you browse a question, there is "Subscribe to this page" button on the address bar.

For bookmark, there is star icon under vote buttons, you just click it, make it gold.

You can see the list later on under your profile

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/262923?tab=favorites#tab-top