# How can I receive notifications about favorite questions?

Tags: support, favorites-notifications

I have read many questions about the topic. Apparently if I favorite a question, I should get notifications about it, but it's currently not the case. Apparently, there is a checkbox in the `prefs` tab of my profile about it. What I see is "Allow email notifications when I subscribe to questions or tags", which I have checked.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to understand how it works: I favorite questions, they get comments, edits, answers, and I am not notified in any way.

I saw info saying that this kind of feature is broken, but it was about a year ago. Certainly I've missed some stuff?

What am I doing wrong? How can I get updates about those questions I'm not involved in (without subscribing to individual RSS feeds)?

Comment: It might be worth adding this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52094/179635 on _"feature is broken"_ (or somewhere near that sentence)