# How can I receive notifications from someone's questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

I sometimes see a good question and I really want to know answers or advice for these questions.

I has voted up them and mark as favorite but I can not receive any notifications about a new answer for this question when them come except questioner. I need to check it by myself.

How can I receive notifications from someone's questions that I interest when a new answers or comments come?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145252/how-can-i-receive-notifications-about-favorite-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Favourites will give updates in your own profile by highlighting Favourites tab.
2. RSS feeds for question is also best to give updates.

For RSS feeds see this posts:

1. [RSS feed for favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25194/rss-feed-for-favorite-questions)
2. [How can I get an RSS feed of just my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55868/how-can-i-get-an-rss-feed-of-just-my-own-questions)

Also see:

[Mark questions to receive notifications and updates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates)

Comment: Thanks you so much. I hope SO will implement this feature soon or have a simpler way to use this.

Comment: How can I allow Favorites to "give updates in my own profile by highlighting Favorites tab"?