# What happened to the idea of getting inbox notifications for favorited questions?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, bookmarks

I was reading one of [Jeff's old posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52094/229166) and was surprised that what he described in a comment *still* hasn't been implemented.

> well, don't thank me yet -- this functionality was pulled, and we
>   haven't quite figured out a way to change it yet. Current thinking is
>   for the star click to trigger a "do you want to be notified about this
>   question?" with some "always do this" options. –  Jeff Atwood♦ Jan 3
>   '12 at 9:03

This sounds like the best idea since toasted waffles, so why hasn't it been implemented yet?

I often find questions that intrest me greatly or I feel may greatly help me in the future. Often these questions might have a good answer at the time or the answer may change due for other reasons (ex. software updates).

I would like a way to recieve updates in my inbox for super-special questions that I designate (a sort of super-favorite). I find the "favorites" tab to be inconvenient and can easily become cluttered if you favorite a lot of questions.

Comment: Side note: There are _many_ posts on the topic of getting notifications for specific questions, however I couldn't find one to serve as canonical reference for all others to be duplicates of. (Someone may want to clean those up)

Comment: *Toasted* waffles? *Toasted*?! BLASPHEMY! Only a true purist can unlock the full potential of the waffl- er, I mean, yeah, great idea

Comment: @Doorknob Leave me waffles instead of cookies this christmas.

Comment: Since [the Follow Questions and Answers feature was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/335251), is this request still relevant/applicable? It's not the same thing as bookmarked questions (aka favorited/starred questions) generating notifications, of course, but the use cases are slightly different.

Comment: Since [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/335251), which work a bit differently, I'm closing this feature request as no longer reproducible.