# Receive notifications for someone's questions in iOS app

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, ios-app

How can I receive notifications on iOS app for questions that I am interested in but which are asked by other people.

Comment: I think that this is more generally addressed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates). There's really not a mechanic (that I'm aware of) to be notified of actions on someone else's questions... even on the actual site, outside of the app... it seems that they made "favorites" send notifications at one point but they since disabled it.