# Option of be notified when a comment is upvoted?

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes, up-votes, options

Is there an option for this or can this ever be implemented into the website?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no option. It has been somewhat suggest before, but I don't believe it will be implemented anywhere in the near future. By somewhat suggested I mean some ideas have alluded to the ability,  or would partially fulfill this ability.

This question is related to
[Notifications for comments on comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/477/what-level-of-notification-should-we-have-regarding-questions-we-have-posted-an-a)
[Recent activity on unowned responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will ever be added. Comments were meant to be a very minor feature. Only recently have you even been able to up-vote a comment.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment there isn't a way to track this