# Get notified on answer on another persons question

Tags: feature-request, questions, notifications, global-inbox

First: I searched, I really did.
I wonder if there is a way to mark another persons question *followed* so when answer appears I am notified within *Stackoverflow inbox*.
I have not been notivifed on activity of any of my favorited questions, so I don't know if *favorite* mark invokes such behaviour, but I doubt it. But I think it should.

Summary:

1. **Can I follow other persons question to be notified on answers?**
2. **If no, shouldn't this behavior apply to *Favorites*?**

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work : *"Changes to the question will eventually (but do not currently) notify users who have favorited the question. Notifications will include comments to the question, edits, new answers, and edits to answers. This is a way to get updates on questions that you yourself didn't ask."*

Comment: Because of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates/52094#52094) I'm still interested what is the current state of this feature - are administrators serious with the implementation?

Comment: The favorites tab in your profile shows a counter for updated favorites and you can see which ones have the newest activity. It's not very useful and extremely hard to find out, but that's the best there currently is

Comment: In the mean time there is a RSS feed for every question on the site. Look at the bottom right side of the page.

Comment: @BenBrocka Thank you. I was always wondering what that blue number means... I thought it is number of favorites I have recently added - just like the other blue shows amount of updated reputation.

Comment: @dmckee: I'd have to implement my own updater that parses RSS. That would take too much time for non-permanent solution.

Comment: I couldn't find the original "send favorite updates to inbox" post to bounty, but IMO with all the focus on changing the duplicate process they really should make it easier to get updates to favorite questions. Tracking a question that isn't yours is still a massive pain

Comment: @BenBrocka Are you referring to: [Mark questions to receive notifications and updates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates/52094)? Or maybe: [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343/200500)

Comment: See also [What level of notification should users have for questions they posted answers to (or left comments on)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/477/195817)  (it’s 3½ years old).